# WebView and HTML5 <video>

Tags: android, html, video, webview, android-webview

I'm piecing together a cheapo app that amongst other things "frames" some of our websites...  Pretty simple with the `WebViewClient`. until I hit the video.

The video is done as `HTML5`  elements, and these work fine and dandy on Chrome, iPhones, and now that we fixed the encoding issues it works great on `Android` in the native browser.

Now the rub: `WebView` doesn't like it.  At all.  I can click on the poster image, and nothing happens.

Googling, I found [this](http://www.codelark.com/2010/05/12/android-viewing-video-from-embedded-webview/) which is close, but seems to be based on a 'link' (as in a href...) instead of a video element.  (onDownloadListener does not appear to get invoked on video elements...)

I also see references to overriding onShowCustomView, but that seems to not get called on video elements... nor does shouldOverrideUrlLoading..

I would rather not get into "pull xml from the server, reformat it in the app".. by keeping the story layout on the server, I can control the content a bit better without forcing people to keep updating an app.  So if I can convince WebView to handle  tags like the native browser, that would be best.

I'm clearly missing something obvious.. but I have no clue what.

Comment: Please see: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22254

Comment: Along these same lines, I'm looking for an HTML5 player for my website.  What should I use?

Comment: My answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16179544/423171

Comment: Nothing worked so I looked into `VideoEnabledWebView` here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview

Answer (score 94, accepted):

It is possible to view a video element (video html5 tag) within a WebView, but I must say I had to deal with it for few days. These are the steps I had to follow so far:

- Find a properly encoded video
- When initializing the WebView, set the JavaScript, Plug-ins the WebViewClient and the WebChromeClient.

  ```
  url = new String("http://broken-links.com/tests/video/"); 
  mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
  mWebView.setWebChromeClient(chromeClient);
  mWebView.setWebViewClient(wvClient);
  mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
  mWebView.loadUrl(url);
  ```
- Handle the onShowCustomView in the WebChromeClient object.

  ```
  @Override
  public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
      super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
      if (view instanceof FrameLayout){
          FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view;
          if (frame.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView){
              VideoView video = (VideoView) frame.getFocusedChild();
              frame.removeView(video);
              a.setContentView(video);
              video.setOnCompletionListener(this);
              video.setOnErrorListener(this);
              video.start();
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Handle the onCompletion and the onError events for the video, in order to get back to the web view.

  ```
  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Video completo");
      a.setContentView(R.layout.main);
      WebView wb = (WebView) a.findViewById(R.id.webview);
      a.initWebView();
  }
  ```

But now I should say there are still an important issue. I can play it only once. The second time I click on the video dispatcher (either the poster or some play button), it does nothing.

I would also like the video to play inside the WebView frame, instead of opening the Media Player window, but this is for me a secondary issue.

Comment: i donot run any result,my screen is black. i want to know if this need thead. my code is too long to posy here.can you give me some contact way or  open a another topic.

Comment: Are you completely sure is not an encoding issue? Try with the URL I posted. Obviously it has to work with the native browser

Comment: thanks, mdelolmo! that got my onShowCustomView to work... will have to play with it.   Note that the emulator (at least on Linux) doesn't like playing videos much at all, even things a real android will play fine.  And encoding is a bit of a pain... took a while to get things set up here so that the droids would stream.

Comment: Thanks mdelolmo!  I tried to figure out the issue with it only playing once and I wrote it up in an answer to this question.

Comment: what is "a"? like that activity would that be?

Comment: @Collin Price a is an instance of the Activity hosting the webview.
@desgraci, I can provide it, but there is not much besides that. Make a class extend `WebChromeClient` and override the corresponding methods you need. If you insist, I can upload the rest of the class later when I get home.

Comment: Not working on ICS since getFocusedChild() is not a VideoView, but a HTML5VFullScreen$SurfaceVideoView. Any idea on how to do on ICS? (see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540654/how-to-get-html5-video-uri-in-html5vfullscreensurfacevideoview-in-android-4-0

Comment: this line gives me the error mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true); all the time ... why???

Comment: a.initWebView() what is it >??

Comment: @zest If I remember correctly, that runs the first snippet, a is the instance of the activity that hosts the webview.

Comment: @mdelolmo if snippet initialize webview from WebChromeClient and allocate memory for client in the same snippet, so it won't work

Comment: `a.setContentView(video);` How do I get the activity instance in my WebChromeClient? Should I pass it in the constructor?

Comment: @PetrPeller, I think that is what I did, yes, but my memory might fail after 4 years :)

Comment: wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON); // new update

Comment: What does this actually do? Remove the videoplayer from the layout and add it again... How can that help?

Answer (score 62):

After long research, I got this thing working. See the following code:

**Test.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public class Test extends Activity {

    HTML5WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mWebView = new HTML5WebView(this);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        } else {    
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.18/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/");
        }

        setContentView(mWebView.getLayout());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mWebView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mWebView.stopLoading();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (mWebView.inCustomView()) {
                mWebView.hideCustomView();
            //  mWebView.goBack();
                //mWebView.goBack();
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

**HTML%VIDEO.java**

```
package com.ivz.idemandtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class HTML5WebView extends WebView {

    private Context                             mContext;
    private MyWebChromeClient                   mWebChromeClient;
    private View                                mCustomView;
    private FrameLayout                         mCustomViewContainer;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback  mCustomViewCallback;

    private FrameLayout                         mContentView;
    private FrameLayout                         mBrowserFrameLayout;
    private FrameLayout                         mLayout;

    static final String LOGTAG = "HTML5WebView";

    private void init(Context context) {
        mContext = context;     
        Activity a = (Activity) mContext;

        mLayout = new FrameLayout(context);

        mBrowserFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(a).inflate(R.layout.custom_screen, null);
        mContentView = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.main_content);
        mCustomViewContainer = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_custom_content);

        mLayout.addView(mBrowserFrameLayout, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS);

        // Configure the webview
        WebSettings s = getSettings();
        s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        s.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
      //  s.setSavePassword(true);
        s.setSaveFormData(true);
        s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
        setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);

        setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        // enable navigator.geolocation 
       // s.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
       // s.setGeolocationDatabasePath("/data/data/org.itri.html5webview/databases/");

        // enable Web Storage: localStorage, sessionStorage
        s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        mContentView.addView(this);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public FrameLayout getLayout() {
        return mLayout;
    }

    public boolean inCustomView() {
        return (mCustomView != null);
    }

    public void hideCustomView() {
        mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if ((mCustomView == null) && canGoBack()){
                goBack();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        private Bitmap      mDefaultVideoPoster;
        private View        mVideoProgressView;

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)
        {
            //Log.i(LOGTAG, "here in on ShowCustomView");
            HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }

            mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
            mCustomView = view;
            mCustomViewCallback = callback;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            System.out.println("customview hideeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
            if (mCustomView == null)
                return;        

            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            mCustomView = null;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

            HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            HTML5WebView.this.goBack();
            //Log.i(LOGTAG, "set it to webVew");
        }


        @Override
        public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {
            //Log.i(LOGTAG, "here in on getVideoLoadingPregressView");

            if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_loading_progress, null);
            }
            return mVideoProgressView; 
        }

         @Override
         public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            ((Activity) mContext).setTitle(title);
         }

         @Override
         public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
             ((Activity) mContext).getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, newProgress*100);
         }

         @Override
         public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
             callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
         }
    }


    static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS =
        new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}
```

**custom_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fullscreen_custom_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/error_console"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**video_loading_progress.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/progress_indicator"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ProgressBar android:id="@android:id/progress"
           style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       <TextView android:paddingTop="5dip"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:text="@string/loading_video" android:textSize="14sp"
           android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
/* //device/apps/common/assets/res/any/http_authentication_colors.xml
**
** Copyright 2006, The Android Open Source Project
**
** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
** you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
** You may obtain a copy of the License at 
**
**     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
**
** Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
** distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
** WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. 
** See the License for the specific language governing permissions and 
** limitations under the License.
*/
-->
<!-- FIXME: Change the name of this file!  It is now being used generically
    for the browser -->
<resources>
    <color name="username_text">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="username_edit">#ff000000</color>

    <color name="password_text">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="password_edit">#ff000000</color>

    <color name="ssl_text_label">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="ssl_text_value">#ffffffff</color>

    <color name="white">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="black">#ff000000</color>



    <color name="geolocation_permissions_prompt_background">#ffdddddd</color>
</resources>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Test"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

Expecting rest of things you can understand.

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer.  Surendra and Malenkiy you both saved my sanity. Worked great for me.

Comment: I agree with George. This is exactly how Android native browser works with VideoView. Seems this is same code as here http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/. It works great for all Android versions (I tested on Android 2.2 and above). Only one thing that I wanted to notice, you should keep in mind that if you change target SDK on something above 13 then your's activity will be recreated on changing orientation. To avoid this either append screenSize to android:configChanges (but in this case you will need use min sdk < 13) or use old target SDK (then you can keep android:configChanges)

Comment: This is giving me a white blank screen on nexus 7 (android 4.1). Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Backbutton doesn't stop the video and the audio still audible, any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: This is what i was searching for exactly same as the native browser flow.. Thanks a Ton Surendra and Malenkiy .

Comment: Can you please upload a sample project on GitHub?

Answer (score 34):

mdelolmo's answer was incredibly helpful, but like he said, the video only plays once and then you can't open it again.

I looked into this a bit and here is what I found, in case any weary WebView travelers like myself stumble on this post in the future.

First off, I looked at the [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) and [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)'s documentation and got a better sense of how those work.  I strongly recommend those.

Then, I looked at the [source code to see how the Android Browser](http://www.google.co.in/codesearch/p?hl=en#8mlkOkTjpMM/src/com/android/browser/BrowserActivity.java&q=android%20package:git://android.git.kernel.org%20onShowCustomView&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc) does it.  Do a page find and go look at how they handle `onShowCustomView()`.   They keep a reference to the `CustomViewCallback`and to the custom view.

With all of that, and with mdelolmo's answer in mind, when you are done with the video, all you need to do is two things.  First, on the `VideoView` that you saved a reference to, call `stopPlayback()` that will release the `MediaPlayer` to be used later elsewhere.  You can see it in the [VideoView](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java) source code.  Second, on the `CustomViewCallback` you saved a reference to call `CustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden()`.

After doing those two things, you can click on the same video or any other video and it will open like before.  No need to restart the entire WebView.

Comment: Actually I kinda solved it too, I just didn't remember to post the solution (shame on me). Just like you, I had to have a look to Android browser's code, and well, not much to add, I used the onCompletion listener to stop the Player instead and had to set visibility's a couple of times, but I would buy your solution. Regards!

Comment: Google Code Search has been retired, I think this version of BrowserActivity.java (from Froyo) roughly corresponds to the one described here: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser/blob/froyo-release/src/com/android/browser/BrowserActivity.java

Comment: @spacemanki's linked code doesn't contain any mentions of VideoView in the whole repo. I guess BrowserActivity does it differently now. I even went back to the Eclair release. Can't find any usage.

Comment: The problem I have with all this is that what I'm getting back from frame.getFocusedChild(); is a HTml5VideoView instead of a ViewView and therefore none of this works for me and cannot switch to fullscreen  :(  I'm on Android 4.1.2.

Comment: Solved it! I just removed the 'if' that checks if it's an instance of ViewView. Finally I can play video in normal size and fullscreen!! :D

Comment: What finally did it for me was to add:   @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        
        mWebView.destroy();
    }   to the activity... the webview.destroy() was crucial

Answer (score 8):

Actually, it seems sufficient to merely attach a stock WebChromeClient to the client view, ala

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

and  you need to have hardware acceleration turned on!

At least, if you don't need to play a full-screen video, there's no need to pull the VideoView out of the WebView and push it into the Activity's view.  It will play in the video element's allotted rect.

Any ideas how to intercept the expand video button?

Comment: you can intercept it using WebChromeClient and overriding onShowCustomView

Comment: Please specify which version of Android. This works differently for different versions.

Answer (score 7):

I know this thread is several months old, but I found a solution for playing the video inside the WebView without doing it fullscreen (but still in the media player...). So far, I didn't find any hint on this in the internet so maybe this is also interesting for others.
I'm still struggling on some issues (i.e. placing the media player in the right section of the screen, don't know why I'm doing it wrong but it's a relatively small issue I think...).

In the Custom ChromeClient specify LayoutParams:

```
// 768x512 is the size of my video
FrameLayout.LayoutParams LayoutParameters = 
                                     new FrameLayout.LayoutParams (768, 512);
```

My onShowCustomView method looks like this:

```
public void onShowCustomView(final View view, final CustomViewCallback callback) {
     // super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
     if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {
         this.mCustomViewContainer = (FrameLayout) view;
         this.mCustomViewCallback = callback;
         this.mContentView = (WebView) this.kameha.findViewById(R.id.webview);
         if (this.mCustomViewContainer.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView) {
             this.mCustomVideoView = (VideoView) 
                                     this.mCustomViewContainer.getFocusedChild();
             this.mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             final int viewWidth = this.mContentView.getWidth();
             final int viewLeft = (viewWidth - 1024) / 2;
             // get the x-position for the video (I'm porting an iPad-Webapp to Xoom, 
             // so I can use those numbers... you have to find your own of course...
             this.LayoutParameters.leftMargin = viewLeft + 256; 
             this.LayoutParameters.topMargin = 128;
             // just add this view so the webview underneath will still be visible, 
             // but apply the LayoutParameters specified above
             this.kameha.addContentView(this.mCustomViewContainer, 
                                             this.LayoutParameters); 
             this.mCustomVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
             this.mCustomVideoView.setOnErrorListener(this);
             // handle clicks on the screen (turning off the video) so you can still
             // navigate in your WebView without having the video lying over it
             this.mCustomVideoView.setOnFocusChangeListener(this); 
             this.mCustomVideoView.start();
         }
     }
 }
```

So, I hope I could help... I too had to play around with video-Encoding and saw different kinds of using the WebView with html5 video - in the end my working code was a wild mix of different code-parts I found in the internet and some things I had to figure out by myself. It really was a pain in the a*.

Comment: On ICS, getFocusedChild() does not return a VideoView. Any idea on how to make this work on ICS?

Answer (score 4):

This approach works well very till 2.3
And by adding hardwareaccelerated=true it even works from 3.0 to ICS
One problem i am facing currently is upon second launch of media player application is getting crashed because i have not stopped playback and released Media player.
As VideoSurfaceView object, which we get in onShowCustomView function from 3.0 OS, are specific to browser and not a VideoView object as in, till 2.3 OS
How can i access it and stopPlayback and release resources?

Answer (score 3):

A-M's is similar to what the [BrowerActivity](http://www.google.co.in/codesearch/p?hl=en#8mlkOkTjpMM/src/com/android/browser/BrowserActivity.java&q=android%20package%3agit://android.git.kernel.org%20onShowCustomView&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc) does. 
for
      FrameLayout.LayoutParams LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams (768, 512);

I think we can use

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)
```

instead.

Another issue I met is if the video is playing, and user clicks the back button, next time, you go to this activity(singleTop one) and can not play the video.  to fix this, I called the

```
try { 
    mCustomVideoView.stopPlayback();  
    mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
} catch(Throwable e) { //ignore }
```

in the activity's onBackPressed method.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an very old question, but have you tried the `hardwareAccelerated="true"` manifest flag for your application or activity?

With this set, it seems to work without any WebChromeClient modification (which I would expect from an DOM-Element.)

Comment: `hardwareAccelerated` starts from Android 3.0

Answer (score 2):

I used [html5webview](http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/) to solve this problem.Download and put it into your project then you can code just like this.

```
private HTML5WebView mWebView;
String url = "SOMEURL";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mWebView = new HTML5WebView(this);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    } else {
            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
    setContentView(mWebView.getLayout());
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mWebView.saveState(outState);
}
```

To make the video rotatable, put android:configChanges="orientation" code into your Activity
for example (Androidmanifest.xml)

```
<activity android:name=".ui.HTML5Activity" android:configChanges="orientation"/>
```

and override the onConfigurationChanged method.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is years old, but maybe my answer will help people like me who have to support old Android version. I tried a lot of different approaches which worked on some Android versions, however not on all. The best solution I found is to use the [Crosswalk Webview](https://crosswalk-project.org) which is optimized for HTML5 feature support and works on Android 4.1 and higher. It is as simple to use as the default Android WebView. You just have to include the library. Here you can find a simple tutorial on how to use it: https://diego.org/2015/01/07/embedding-crosswalk-in-android-studio/

Comment: Note: Crosswalk is **not maintained** anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Well, apparently this is just not possible without using a JNI to register a plugin to get the video event.  (Personally, I am avoiding JNI's since I really don't want to deal with a mess when Atom-based android tablets come out in the next few months, losing the portability of Java.)

The only real alternative seems to be to create a new web page just for WebView and do video the old-school way with an A HREF link as cited in the Codelark url above.

Answer (score 1):

On honeycomb use `hardwareaccelerated=true` and `pluginstate.on_demand` seems to work

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I had HTML files and videos in the assets-folder of my app.

Therefore the videos were located inside of the APK. Because the APK is really a ZIP-file, the WebView was not able to read the video-files.

Copying all HTML- and video-files onto the SD-Card worked for me.