# Does android webview supports html5 video play?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WebView and HTML5 <video>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video)

Hi
Can anybody tell me 
Do android webview supports html5 video play??
if yes can you please tell me how ?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. It does, but you have to *write* more code, not just using WebView, see the following links for more information:

- [WebView and HTML5 <video>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video)
- [How to play a video in a webview with android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989738/how-to-play-a-video-in-a-webview-with-android)

And a working example for Android 2.2
 - http://www.tandroid.org/html5webview

Comment: Yes, and I found you don't need to add any extra code, at least under 4.x. What I did find was if you use a "supports-screens" entry in your AndroidManifest.xml, that you set the anyDensity=true. Otherwise it will play audio track but show no video.