# WebView NOT opening android default video player?

Tags: java, android, webview

when I view [this page](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/30/encoding-video-for-android/) on my android device' default web browser and click the first video, it triggers the default video player of my device. It loads and play.

However when I view the same link in my app, using a WebView, it does not open the default video player. What could be the problem?

I'm using the webview code in [this link](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/05/how-to-view-webpage-inside-your-android.html).

I also made the webview in full screen mode like what was said in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.0-highlights.html), is used this code to go fullscreen:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

EDIT: I'm now using the following code, but still not work, any ideas?

```
package com.example.Playmp4OnWebView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class PlayMp4OnWebView extends Activity {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
          getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

          WebView webview = new WebView(this);
          setContentView(webview);

          WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
          webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
          webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
          webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
          webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

          webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

              public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                   if(url.endsWith(".mp4")){
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(i); //warning no error handling will cause force close if no media player on phone.
                        return true;
                   }
                   else return false; 
              }});

       //This will load the webpage that we want to see
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/30/encoding-video-for-android/");

     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to attach your own [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) and override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` if you detect a URL with a supported video mimetype return true and then launch the default activity with the URL. Here is an untested sample.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(Webview view, String url){
     if(url.endsWith(".mp4") || url.endsWith("some other supported type")){
          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
          startActivity(i); //warning no error handling will cause force close if no media player on phone.
          return true;
     }
     else return false; 
}});
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @schwiz, thanks a lot for your response, I updated the question with my updated code and your suggestion code. But it still doesn't trigger the default media player of my device. Any ideas?

Comment: @Kris well if its loading in the same webview instead of launching an activity or forceclosing then the URL must not end with mp4 I would set a breakpoint in shouldOverrideUrlLoading and see what's happening in there.

Comment: when I click the vid, nothing happnes, it does not load or launch any activity or force closing. Actually, the first vid im clicking does not use href, it uses html5 <video> tag. so it think it wont detect your condition url.endswith(".mp4"). any ideas on how can i detect clicking the <video> tag to launch the default video player?

Comment: Well anyway, I'm now using the android default video view to play those videos I have from the sdcard... Thanks :)

Comment: @Kris best advice I can give is to put a break point or print to the logs the URL and see what you are clicking on and think of a way to test for it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting a `html5` video tag in the `WebView` then the above code (using WebViewClient) will not be called, instead you will have to handle it with `WebChromeClient` as shown in the bellow link

[How to play a video in a webview with android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989738/how-to-play-a-video-in-a-webview-with-android)

I have tried it out and it worked well :)

the above code (using WebViewClient) is useful only when we have to handle a redirect request to another page via user click on anchor tag or through any hyperlink in the `WebView`