# Android: how to detect a video is being played in WebView?

Tags: android, webview, android-video-player

I am working on an App and YouTube.com is embedded into a WebView. Videos cannot be played when I click any ones (it is in loading status forever). So I try to use VideoView or YouTubePlayerFragment to play videos when user clicks video play button. My question is: Are there any ways to detect that user has clicked play button?

I added below listener on WebView, but the hr is insufficient to tell use clicks play button.

```
    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView)v).getHitTestResult();

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you find any solution lately>?

Comment: @WideFide, I don't know the root cause but it turns out that youtube view cannot be played in webview because i set android:layerType="software" for webview in the layout. After I remove this from layout, videos can be played and paused.

Comment: please check this :[my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811748/html5-in-a-webview-detect-when-video-is-started/44397791#44397791)

Answer (score -1):

After investigation, I use the solution provided in other posts:
[WebView link click open default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229494/webview-link-click-open-default-browser)
and [Support for other protocols in Android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583264/support-for-other-protocols-in-android-webview)

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        String string = "YouTube URL regular expression";
        if (url.toLowerCase().matches(string)) {
            launchInBrowserOrYouTubeApp(url);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

There is still one issue for this solution. When I click any videos for the first time, this method is triggered and the url is 'www.youtube.com' (the url is 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajsdfhjh' when I  click any videos second times or more), which is exact the same when the webview is initialized. So I cannot tell if it is user who clicks a video or it is the webview initialization.