# YouTube video is not opening in webView

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube

The problem is that I can load YouTube site, and navigate trough videos,

but when I click to play a video nothing happens.

Video just get orange flash like it is selected,

but doesn't start loading or playing.

I am using Android 2.2.

the methods that I am using in web View are:

**webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);**

[image]

any help is highly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to connect via http or rtsp?

Comment: have you checked this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861285/webview-youtube-videos-not-playing

Comment: Why are using this method? it would be far better if its a single video to upload it somewhere and have it stream in a VideoView. Or if there are more then 1 video - use Intent to launch the youtube app - since pretty much every android comes with this app pre-installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found that the YouTube is working in default browser  used.. this work around.. to get it working..

```
if (url.contains("youtube")) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
} else {
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the HTML5 video player source code from [here](https://code.google.com/p/html5webview/source/checkout)