# play youtube video in WebView android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-webview

I want to play **Youtube video** in my WebView. I know this is a duplicate question on StackOverflow but still I didn't get solution for it.

I use android 2.2 and higher. I tried HTML5 but it's not supported in my device. 
I was googling from last 5 days.

Comment: check the links given at answer given by me at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208439/html5-video-doesnt-play-with-android/10209684#10209684  it works for me that example download that example using svn and check it

Comment: But HTML5 supported in android 3.0 and up.

Comment: @ you want play video from links right it works i have checked that in my project first download sample and check it it show different option  for playing video like 3gp,mp4 etc also from links and after that in class replace the link by your links it works i have checked eith version 2.3.1 with htmlstring containg description and video and image gallary too

Comment: I found only apk file not source on your link.

Comment: I write following code for load URL in my webview. `webview.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+data.split("v=")[1].split("&")[0]);`

Comment: But it open Youtube.com web brower and video play on youtube not in my application. I want to play it withing my application(my webview). Give me any source code for this same please.

Comment: @go to link source where links is given for source

Comment: I dont get source from your link it contains only apk file. Please give me any other source.

Comment: you get source from this links http://html5webview.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ from given at as on my links

Comment: But HTML5 Webview is not supported in my android 2.2 platform.

Comment: @hardikjoshi pls share how u solved this issue?

Comment: @parag i use http://blog.blundell-apps.com/click-item-in-a-listview-to-show-youtube-video/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Google's own android api for youtube found at https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/