# Play youtube video In App in android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

In my android application I want to play youtube video in App, not in the default browser. I am trying this for the last some days. Previously I played the youtube video using the following code :
http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/downloads/list

But now this code is not working. It shows "Sorry, this video cannot be played." I have tried all the possible solution mentioned in the different forum for this error. But could not be able to play the video.
That's why I am trying to find out another way to play the video in app. I have tried the RTSP link of a youtube video , it is playing the 3gp video file, but video quality is very poor. This is not acceptable.
I am really fade up to find out good solution to play youtube video in app.
Please help. Any good suggestion is always welcome.
Santanu

Answer (score 2):

Playing YouTube videos in Android was made very simple with the release of this library: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/. The Developer Guide on that page is a good resource on how to use this library. They also provide sample code on how to use the functionality provided by the library. The steps are basically:

1. Get a developer key
2. Download the library and include it in your project
3. Use the library to play videos (hint. use the YouTubePlayerView as a first step)

Please post again if you have any questions or need any code examples.

Comment: Hi i have using there jar only.here i have using youtubeplayersupportfragment.here i have facing follwoing issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494249/video-playback-displays-blank-screen-with-only-audio  please check that and give me solution for these.

Answer (score 0):

I play youtube video in videoview and I also face problem regarding video result.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1405983%20youtube) some topics regarding this. One my friend suggest me use `embeded` URL instead of `rtsp` URL. Its give good result. For Example [embeded URL example](http://www.youtube.com/embed/) and [how to implement it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208439/html5-video-doesnt-play-with-android/10209684#10209684)