# video playback displays blank screen with only audio?

Tags: android, video, android-fragments, youtube-api

I have to develop an one android application.

here i have to play the youtube video on full screen mode and normal mode.

i have  using youtubeplayerfragment.

Here the video is playing well on fullscreen mode.

The Same video is didnot play on normal mode.

My Exact problem is,

When I try to play the video, all I get is blank video but I get all the audio and subtitles.

If I hit the back button, I see the last video frame before the video player closes.

Why am facing these issue ???

please give me any solution ??

am using following xml code:

```
<fragment
  android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
  android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_below="@+id/title"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

This is activity code:

```
    _Video = articlevideo.substring(1);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
          FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                  .beginTransaction();
        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment fragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, fragment); 
         fragmentTransaction.commit();


       fragment.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {


            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                    YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    player.cueVideo(_Video);
                }
            }
            private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                    YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {


              if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
                errorReason.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
              } else {
                String errorMessage = String.format(getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
            }

        });
```

Whats wrong in my code .please give me any suggestions .

Comment: Your question is not clear, please rewrite

Comment: What android version are you using? What phone?

Comment: @J.Romero i have developing the app in 4.2 version(jelly bean,samsang NOTE).

Comment: @user2218667 Have you solved this? I am facing same issue lately.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [YouTube Direct Lite App](https://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/ytdl/DirectFragment.java) as a reference.
While switching to full screen or orintation change, activity is killed and created again in Android. So you may need something like

android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >

Check the [manifest](https://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/source/browse/trunk/AndroidManifest.xml) for it.