# How to play a youtube video in a default video player from a webview?

Tags: java, android

I have a webview which loads a website with some thumbnail of youtube video, I dont have any control to edit that webpage, now what I want to do is if user clicks the video thumbnail then the video will be played in a default video player of that device or in a new landscape activity as default youtube application do, as far as I did it opens the video in that webview but I want to open that in a video player, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a new Intent. In that open a media player and get the video of you tube there and try to stop the webview video and do loading in the background. 
You can get more help here [WebView NOT opening android default video player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247146/webview-not-opening-android-default-video-player) .

Answer (score 0):

If you can access a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), then you can start an Activity with an appropriate Intent. Android will then choose the correct App or prompt the user to choose one.