# Playing Embedded Audio Through WebView Android

Tags: android, audio, iframe, webview, android-mediaplayer

I have searched numerous places and have failed to find the solution to my problem.

I have a WebView in my android app and body of the HTML contains an iframe. The iframe is actually a media file from mixlr (I'm not sure if this matters). When I press anywhere on the WebView it prompts me, "Open with streaming media player". I want the audio to start playing directly from the webview without having to switch apps.

This solution:

[WebView NOT opening android default video player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247146/webview-not-opening-android-default-video-player)

prevented the popup from occurring but instead threw an ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.

The weird thing is, it was working before. It would automatically start streaming the audio without prompts (I forget if this was prior to switching to Lollipop). I'm suspecting this is because of an android update because it went from no prompt to prompting without having installed a new build. If this is the reason, is there any way to prevent this from happening and stream the audio straight from WebView.

I've also looked into MediaPlayer. This solution doesn't work for me because mixlr doesn't give you an mp3 embed file but rather an iframe.

Comment: have you implemented webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Yes, it results in the same error. Unless there is a specific implementation of WebChromeClient Which I haven't tried.