# How to open external player when using WebView?

Tags: android, video, webview

How to open external video player when using WebView on JS site? I try to open an external video player through the android application on the webview, but nothing works.

file MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://google.com/");
    WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            return true;
        }

    };
    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
}
```

};

I tried using this code but nothing comes out

```
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.contains(".avi") || url.contains(".ts") || url.contains(".mkv") || url.contains(".mp4")){
               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
                intent.setDataAndType( videoUri, "application/x-mpegURL" );
                startActivity( intent );
                return true;
           }else {

                return false;
        }

        }
```

Comment: Hi Jo... Hope this solves the problem you are facing ->  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6247313/6826629

Comment: I still did not understand the answer, the link leads to the question of how to open the video in the webview itself.....

Comment: There are no tags in the video link.

Comment: The link is not intercepted on the JS website/