# Load video from SDcard to webview

Tags: android, video, webview

Is it possible to load a mp4 video from SDcard into an `WebView` on android? I need to play a video from Sdcard, but not into a `VideoView`. If yes, can you provide an example ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989738/how-to-play-a-video-in-a-webview-with-android