# Android video poster displaced after playback in webview

Tags: android, video, android-webview

Following the advice here: [How to play a video in a webview with android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989738/how-to-play-a-video-in-a-webview-with-android)

I was able to play a video in a webview called from JS.
However after playback the poster image for the video gets displaced.
With the test js:

```
var anchor = "<button id=\"open\" type='button'>openLink</button><button type='button' onclick='playPause();'>Play/Pause</button>"+"<video id='video' poster='{imageURL}' onclick='this.play();'><source src='{videoURL}'</video>";
```

Initially The page is displayed with two buttons followed by the poster image.
After the video is played the poser image is displayed on top of the buttons centered on screen.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks