# How to implement onShowCustomView method?

Tags: android, video, webview, webchromeclient

I want to play a video on a webview. For that I've found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video)  but I can't understand how to implement the `onShowCustomView` method of the `WebChromeClient`.

I am using Android SDK 1.6. Is there an issue regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

There's an implementation by "cprcrack" in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview)
Didn't test it yet but it makes sense and very descriptive.