# playing video on android webview does not fullscreen

Tags: android, android-webview, html5-video

I am making a webview application which shows pages they have html5 videos in it. when I tap the fullscreen, video dissapears.

when I searching same problems, saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15768837/1265083) question, which is same problem with me, and thought 2nd answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16179544/1265083)) fits for me also.
Even I use classes given in the answer, I am still having these errors and application stoped.

```
05-03 13:41:50.064: E/AndroidRuntime(19292): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 13:41:50.064: E/AndroidRuntime(19292): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 13:41:50.064: E/AndroidRuntime(19292):    at com.zapkolik.mayis.VideoEnabledWebChromeClient.onShowCustomView(VideoEnabledWebChromeClient.java:132)
05-03 13:41:50.064: E/AndroidRuntime(19292):    at android.webkit.HTML5VideoFullscreen.enterFullscreen(HTML5VideoFullscreen.java:239)
05-03 13:41:50.064: E/AndroidRuntime(19292):    at android.webkit.HTML5VideoView.enterFullscreenVideoState(HTML5VideoView.java:544)
05-03 13:41:50.064: E/AndroidRuntime(19292):    at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy$VideoPlayer.enterFullscreenVideo(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:182)
05-03 13:41:50.064: E/AndroidRuntime(19292):    at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy.handleMessage(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:479)
05-03 13:41:50.064: E/AndroidRuntime(19292):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
.
.
.
```

my activity is here:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.zapkolik.mayis;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.text.method.HideReturnsTransformationMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private VideoEnabledWebView webView;
private VideoEnabledWebChromeClient webChromeClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Save the web view
    webView = (VideoEnabledWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    // Initialize the VideoEnabledWebChromeClient and set event handlers
    View nonVideoLayout = findViewById(R.id.nonVideoLayout); // Your own view, read class comments
    ViewGroup videoLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.video_layout); // Your own view, read class comments
    View loadingView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.loading_video, null);
// Your own view, read class comments

    final Activity activity = this;
    webChromeClient = new VideoEnabledWebChromeClient(nonVideoLayout, videoLayout, loadingView, webView) // See all available constructors...
    {
        // Subscribe to standard events, such as onProgressChanged()...

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        }
    };
    webChromeClient.setOnToggledFullscreen(new VideoEnabledWebChromeClient.ToggledFullscreenCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void toggledFullscreen(boolean fullscreen)
        {
//              AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create(); //Read Update
//              alertDialog.setTitle("hi");
//              alertDialog.setMessage("this is my app");
        }
    });
    webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    // Navigate everywhere you want, this classes have only been tested on YouTube's mobile site
    webView.loadUrl("http://m.youtube.com");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // Notify the VideoEnabledWebChromeClient, and handle it ourselves if it doesn't handle it
    if (!webChromeClient.onBackPressed())
    {
        if (webView.canGoBack())
        {
            webView.goBack();
        }
        else
        {
            // Close app (presumably)
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}

}
```

and layouts are:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nonVideoLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.zapkolik.mayis.VideoEnabledWebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**loading_video.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/center"
    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="208dp"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.39" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**video_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VideoView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I could not figure out why I am getting errors when I tap the fullscreen button.

Comment: have you managed to solve it?

Comment: not yet, actually that mobile project canceled for now.

Comment: did u get the solution

Comment: Sorry, it was problem of its time, android and webview had many newer version. I don't think problem occurs for recent version. I'm not developing neither java nor android apps. Sorry to not helping you.