# Triggering fullscreen video playback on Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, html5-video, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

i am trying to trigger a video to playback in fullscreen mode when you tap it to start playing it on an Android device (specifically Chrome on a Google Nexus 7) and then close fullscreen mode when the video has ended. I have tried both the webkitRequestFullScreen() and webkitEnterFullScreen() methods. The latter works just fine on iOS but Android 4.2.2 just ignores it totally. I have done a lot of googling on this issue but can't find a definitive answer on it. Anyone know why i can't get fullscreen to fire?

Here is my code:

```
function movPlaying() {
    this.webkitEnterFullScreen();
}

function movEnded() {
    this.webkitExitFullScreen();
}

var video_1 = document.getElementById("video_1");
video_1.addEventListener('play', movPlaying);
video_1.addEventListener('ended', movEnded);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your trying to achieve the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview) guy.

If you want to try it, there is a package for fullscreen [here](http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen). Maybe you can use some of his examples.

Comment: Tried the David Walsh stuff and it doesn't work for me. The other link seemed to be about trying to achieve it in java and i need to do it solely in javascript. Thanks for the links though.