# Android: Playing html videos in full screen

Tags: javascript, android-webview, android-video-player, android-fullscreen, android-jsinterface

I am loading a HTML page on to a webview, which has a list of videos.
Now when I try to play the videos, they are playing but I am unable to make them play in full screen. I have used the below code in my HTML file, and on debugging found that 'element.webkitRequestFullScreen' says 'undefined'. On searching the web , I found videoEl.webkitEnterFullScreen();, but read that this is not working on Android 4. Is it actually possible to do this? or shall I drop the idea?

```
 function launchFullScreen(element) {
    alert("launchFullScreen"+element.webkitRequestFullScreen);
      if (element.requestFullScreen) {
        element.requestFullScreen();
      } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Webview if you want to play a html video in full screen use this code https://github.com/mickyarun/VideoEnabledWebView

Answer (score 0):

if you are ok solving it in java/android, then try this [guy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview). I adapted it for my needs and must say it works fine. Remember to call onHideCustomView manually when exiting fullscreen by means of the back button. This does not work on all devices (like the S3).

But if you are looking for element.webkitRequestFullScreen(); to work Im all ears. Same issue here atm.