# Playing HTML5 video on fullscreen in android webview with custom adapter view

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, html5-video

I am in a project in which I am handling some 10 web-views with HTML5 videos embedded. These web-views are handled with a custom Adapter View. The HTML5 video gets played properly and for handling full screen in a web-view I found a working link

[Playing HTML5 video on fullscreen in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview)

This code is working perfectly when I try with Gallery but when I use the same with my own custom Adapter View the full screen is not popping up.

For the past one week i stuck up with this. Kindly help me.

Here is my detailed code

(MainActivity.java)

```
package com.example.testlayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    GalleryWebView g = new GalleryWebView(this);
    g.setAdapter(new WebAdapter(this));
    setContentView(g);

}

public class WebAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
 private Context mContext;
    public WebAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       WebPageView mWeb = new WebPageView(mContext);
        return mWeb;
    }
  }
}
```

(GalleryWebView.java)

```
package com.example.testlayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class GalleryWebView extends AdapterView {

public GalleryWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/** The adapter with all the data */
private Adapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    // if we don't have an adapter, we don't need to do anything
    if (mAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getChildCount() == 0 ) {
        int position = 0;
        int bottomEdge = 0;
        while (bottomEdge < getHeight() && position < mAdapter.getCount()) {
            View newBottomChild = mAdapter.getView(position, null, this);
            addAndMeasureChild(newBottomChild);
            bottomEdge += newBottomChild.getMeasuredHeight();
            position++;
        }
    }

    positionItems();
}

/**
 * Adds a view as a child view and takes care of measuring it
 *
 * @param child The view to add
 */
private void addAndMeasureChild(View child) {
    LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
    if (params == null) {
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    }
    addViewInLayout(child, -1, params, true);

    int itemWidth = getWidth();
    int itemHeight = getHeight();
    child.measure(MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | itemWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | itemHeight);
}

/**
 * Positions the children at the &quot;correct&quot; positions
 */
private void positionItems() {
    int top = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index< getChildCount(); index++) {
        View child = getChildAt(index);

        int width = child.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        int left = (getWidth() - width) / 2;

        child.layout(left, top, left + width, top + height);
        top += height;
    }
}


@Override
public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
    mAdapter = adapter;
    removeAllViewsInLayout();
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
public Adapter getAdapter() {
    return mAdapter;
}

@Override
public void setSelection(int position) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
}

@Override
public View getSelectedView() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
}
}
```

(WebPageView.java)

```
package com.example.testlayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class WebPageView extends FrameLayout {

private Context                             mContext;
private MyWebChromeClient                   mWebChromeClient;
private View                                mCustomView;
private FrameLayout                         mCustomViewContainer;
private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback  mCustomViewCallback;

private FrameLayout                         mContentView;
private FrameLayout                         mBrowserFrameLayout;

FrameLayout mLayout1;
private WebView web;

private void init(Context context) {
    mContext = context;     
    mBrowserFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_screen, null);
    mContentView = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.main_content);
    mCustomViewContainer = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_custom_content);
    web = (WebView) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.web);

    mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
    web.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
    web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    // Configure the webview
    WebSettings s = web.getSettings();
    s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    s.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    s.setSavePassword(true);
    s.setSaveFormData(true);
    s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // enable Web Storage: localStorage, sessionStorage
    s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("file:///mnt/sdcard/htmlad/htmlad/index.html");

    addView(mBrowserFrameLayout);
}

public WebPageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public WebPageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public WebPageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}


private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    private Bitmap      mDefaultVideoPoster;
    private View        mVideoProgressView;

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)
    {
        web.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (mCustomView != null) {
            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
            return;
        }
        mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
        mCustomView = view;
        mCustomViewCallback = callback;
        mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {

    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster() {
        if (mDefaultVideoPoster == null) {
            mDefaultVideoPoster = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
        return mDefaultVideoPoster;
    }

    @Override
    public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {

        if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_loading_progress, null);
        }
        return mVideoProgressView; 
    }

     @Override
     public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
        ((Activity) mContext).setTitle(title);
     }

     @Override
     public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
         ((Activity) mContext).getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, newProgress*100);
     }
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading: "+url);
        // don't override URL so that stuff within iframe can work properly
        // view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
}

static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS =
    new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}
```

(custom_screen.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_custom_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:visibility="gone"/>  

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <WebView android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```