# html5 mediaplayer to play youtube video

Tags: android, youtube, html5-video

I want to play youtube videos with html5 on my android device. I would also like to add some css and change to media control. How can I achieve this? Is there any good place to start or some sample application?

Comment: You need to elaborate your question more clearly to get more attention.

Comment: Couldn't you simply use iframe with the link of the video you'd like to watch? Can you elaborate a little more/have you tried implementing any code?

Comment: I want to palay youtube video with CSS and javascript from local file inside assets. or I want to play youtube video on html5. How is this possible?

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16179544/1332892

Comment: use chrome client in android

Answer (score 4):

You may want to consider trying to using the [YouTube Embedded API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) inside an Android [WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

Essentially you would create an `Activity` that contains a `WebView` that loads an HTML file that contains the youtube `<iframe>`.

The YouTube Embedded API doesn't allow for complete customization but there are some parameters for changing colors and control styles.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the [videojs-youtube-plugin](https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube), it´s based on [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/).

Videojs is one of the best HTML5 video player, we use it every time we have to include a video.

It´s fully customizable for the desgin of controls and many other options.
It uses the HTML5 video tag and no iframes!
For older devices/browsers it has a Fallback.
It´s just awesome^^

Answer (score 1):

[Sample app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thefinestartist.simpleyoutubeplayer)

[Code](https://gist.github.com/TheFinestArtist/5545437)

[Source Code](https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/SimpleYouTubePlayer/archive/master.zip)

Also add this code to Mainfest -

```
<activity
    android:name="com.sample.android.YouTubePlayerActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="sensor"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
</activity>
```

HOW TO USE

Put Youtube_api_key in YouTubePlayerActivity

```
public static final String GOOGLE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyAOfxiG4aV66h3XmssCEkP3qCvCq******";
```

Get Youtube Video id from URL

```
final String videoId = YouTubePlayerActivity.getYouTubeVideoId("VideoURL");
```

Add video id as Extra and Start Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YouTubePlayerActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(YouTubePlayerActivity.EXTRA_VIDEO_ID, videoId);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

EDIT

You can also customize YouTube Video using [YouTube Player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo?csw=1)