# Fatal signal 11 after Fragment animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I'm currently trying to implement fragment transaction animation like this (Fragment related classes are imported from support library):

```
FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
trans.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in,R.anim.slide_out);
trans.replace(R.id.preview_panel, fragment);
trans.commit();
```

The animations are defined like this:

**slide_in.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

**slide_out.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

Now whenever I run the transaction piece of code once it works fine. However when I run it a second time the app crashes with the following error:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xff000008 (code=1), thread 11015
```

Whenever I remove the setCustomAnimations line this piece of code works fine every time it is run. What could be the issue here and how would I able able to solve/workaround it?

**EDIT:** Managed to narrow down the issue a little bit:

It happens when the fragment being replaced transaction contains a webview with the VideoEnabledWebChromeClient shown in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview) attached.

The error also only occurs on the fade out animation (that's why it seemed like it was only occuring the second time). When I change the animation to `trans.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.eqdpost_slide_in,0);` a it works fine.

Comment: I cannot tell you much with this piece of code, but this error happens often when you are trying to draw something outside the boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what was causing this issue.

It was this method in the fragment participating in the transaction, which is fired when the slide out animation occurs:

```
   @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        _webView.destroy();
        _webView = null;
    }
```

The `_webView.destroy()` call releases the webview from memory. However, for some reason the `_webView = null;` statement doesn't just set the _webView pointer to null, it also calls the `destroy()` method on the webview on a native level before setting the _webView pointer to null.
Because the webview has already been destroyed once the `_webView = null;` is called, it came up with the native error.

Changing the method as shown below fixes the issue:

```
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        _webView = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue which I resolved by upgrading `support-v4` library to `23.1.0` (from `23.0.1`):

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'`