# Unable to Full Screen Youtube Video Inside Custom Webview

Tags: android, webview, youtube

**Update**

I have updated my question to hide confidential code.

If still there is some confusion pls msg me in comments.

**Question**

I have written an custom Webview for playing youtube video embedded in my website to go full Screen.

But its still not Working..
.
kindly Help

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {

          final Context context = this;
        private WebView webView;
         private ImageButton btnrefresh;    
         private TextView txtrefresh;
           private myWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient;
         private Menu optionsMenu;
         private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback customViewCallback;
            private View mCustomView;       
            private FrameLayout customViewContainer;


        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //Tushar
              customViewContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.customViewContainer);
            //Tushar
            //define button 
            btnrefresh = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

            btnrefresh.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnrefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //define textView
            txtrefresh = (TextView)findViewById((R.id.textView1));
            txtrefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            if(isConnected())
            {

                webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);       
                   webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

                    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
                    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
                    webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
            //  webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
              webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
              {
              @Override
              public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


                  if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                      sendEmail(url.substring(7));
                      return true;
                  }

                  return false;
              }

            });


                initWebView(webView);                         
                webView.loadUrl("http://Example.com/");             

                }


            else
            {

            RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativelayout1);
            rel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v){
                 refresh();
               }
           });
                btnrefresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                txtrefresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Internet Connection !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }       
        }

        public boolean inCustomView() {
            return (mCustomView != null);
        }

        public void hideCustomView() {
            mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            webView.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            webView.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            if (inCustomView()) {
                hideCustomView();
            }
        }

        //tushar
        class myWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
            private Bitmap mDefaultVideoPoster;
            private View mVideoProgressView;

            @Override
            public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation, CustomViewCallback callback) {
               onShowCustomView(view, callback);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void onShowCustomView(View view,CustomViewCallback callback) {

                // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
                if (mCustomView != null) {
                    callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                    return;
                }
                mCustomView = view;
                webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                customViewContainer.addView(view);
                customViewCallback = callback;
            }

            @Override
            public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {

                if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
                    mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_progress, null);
                }
                return mVideoProgressView;
            }

            @Override
            public void onHideCustomView() {
                super.onHideCustomView();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
                if (mCustomView == null)
                    return;

                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // Hide the custom view.
                mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // Remove the custom view from its container.
                customViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
                customViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

                mCustomView = null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: when you press on the full screen button does the view freeze up?

Comment: No, Nothing Happens, Video keeps on Playing as usual.. I have done hardware acceleration true

Comment: No one up for a hundred Bounty ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this you should:

1. Implement `showCustomView` and `hideCustomView` methods of `WebChromeClient`.
2. Set `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to your `MainActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

There are two classes that inherit the `WebChromeClient` in your code (`myWebChromeClient` and `MyWebChromeClient`). The first implements `showCustomView` and `hideCustomView` methods and it seems fully working with full-screen video. The second one don't. But you (accidentally?) set the second as `WebChromeClient` to your `WebView`.

To fix this just change the line

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
```

to

```
mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
```

in your `initWebView()` method.

**UPD:**

To lock orientation on *portrait* in normal (not full-screen) mode add following line into `onHideCustomView()` method:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

To let the system decide the best orientation in full-screen mode add this line to `onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback)` method:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Comment: Sir I have wriiten   android:screenOrientation="portrait" > in my manifest.
but can i see the video in landscape mode too ?? programitically ?

Comment: @tusharnarang Yes, it is possible. See my updated answer.

Comment: Sir this is working fine, But the webview is too slow.. takes a minute to load the website

Comment: The website I m using is a responsive wordpress site. With heavy Images and database. the issue is the webview does not show a loading bar.. There is a blank white screen for first 20 seconds

Comment: Have you tried to optimize you web site and internet connection?

Comment: Internet is 8 mbps. And website takes much less time in chrome app

Comment: In computer browser it takes 10 seconds |||||||||||||||

In chrome app android it takes 20 seconds|||||||||||||||||

In my app it takes upto a minute

Comment: @erakitin : The app crashes when i try to tilt my phone to landscape mode when playing video full screen

Comment: @tusharnarang try to add `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` to your `MainActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. It should fix the crash.

Comment: Ok sir, Thanks i will try that,  can u pls suggest something to show a progress bar and increase speed.. The default spinner of the website shows after 20 seconds in my app

Comment: @erakitin : yes the app doesnt crasgh.. But when I press back button the app starts working in landscape mode.. The app should always be in portrait mode except when playing video

Comment: @tusharnarang be sure that `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` is called. If it is not add this line where it is required.

Comment: I have no idea how to increase the speed of `WebView` in your case. The solution depends on the specific situation and it is beyond the scope of this issue.

Comment: @erakitin : I m Sire i have called the setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);   onHIde

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80738/discussion-between-tushar-narang-and-erakitin).

Answer (score 4):

**Working Perfectly.**

Tested on Android 9.0 version

**This is the final thing worked**

Set The setWebChromeClient on webview

**mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChrome());**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView mWebView;


    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);


        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChrome());    // here
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

       if (savedInstanceState == null) {
          mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");
       }

    }


    private class MyChrome extends WebChromeClient {

        private View mCustomView;
        private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
        protected FrameLayout mFullscreenContainer;
        private int mOriginalOrientation;
        private int mOriginalSystemUiVisibility;

        MyChrome() {}

        public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster()
        {
            if (mCustomView == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), 2130837573);
        }

        public void onHideCustomView()
        {
            ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(this.mCustomView);
            this.mCustomView = null;
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility);
            setRequestedOrientation(this.mOriginalOrientation);
            this.mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
            this.mCustomViewCallback = null;
        }

        public void onShowCustomView(View paramView, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback paramCustomViewCallback)
        {
            if (this.mCustomView != null)
            {
                onHideCustomView();
                return;
            }
            this.mCustomView = paramView;
            this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
            this.mOriginalOrientation = getRequestedOrientation();
            this.mCustomViewCallback = paramCustomViewCallback;
            ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(this.mCustomView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1));
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(3846 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
        }
    }

 @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mWebView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

**In AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
```

[Solution Original Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56186877/7402328)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the code Sheharyar Ejaz has posted, I replaced 2 lines to improve the result.

THe first line I replaced is in onShowCustomView, so when user click Youtube fullscreen option of a video, the video will automatically expand into lansdcape fullscreen like native Youtube.

To achieve that, I replaced this line :

```
this.mOriginalOrientation = getRequestedOrientation();
```

with this line :

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

The second line I replaced is in onHideCustomView, so when user minimize the fullscreen video, it will revert into the phone's present layout.

What I do is I replaced this line :

```
this.mOriginalOrientation = getRequestedOrientation();
```

with this line :

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

But, quite different with the suggestion by erakitin, I did not set `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to my MainActivity/WebView Activity in AndroidManifest.xml.