# App rejected because YouTube videos can play when screen is off

Tags: android, wordpress, android-studio, webview, youtube

I made an app that shows my Web site that has youtube videos in it. I used this code to play it in full screen: [Playing HTML5 video on fullscreen in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview/16179544#16179544)
Now I submitted the app for review and Google rejected it because it can keep playing the videos when you lock the screen.
How can I disable this behavior so they approve my app?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about app stores are off-topic. See meta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this [article](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/). The following code shows you if screen is turned off or not

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        // INITIALIZE RECEIVER
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        // YOUR CODE
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // WHEN THE SCREEN IS ABOUT TO TURN OFF
        if (ScreenReceiver.wasScreenOn) {
            // THIS IS THE CASE WHEN ONPAUSE() IS CALLED BY THE SYSTEM DUE TO A SCREEN STATE CHANGE
            System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED OFF");
        } else {
            // THIS IS WHEN ONPAUSE() IS CALLED WHEN THE SCREEN STATE HAS NOT CHANGED
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Then you can call  `webView.onPause();`

A second way to solve your problem would be just to override `onPause()` method on activity like this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    webView.onPause();
}
```

It works for me

Comment: Thank you very much! The second way you wrote worked fine and Google approved my app :)

Answer (score 2):

After some research based on @BooDoo s onPause implementation, I found that not only `onPause` exists for the webview, it also has an `onResume` method.

So designing your activity that plays a video with these events, it should go ok:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    webView.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    webView.onResume();
}
```

The Resume event lets your video player continue at the same position where you left when you paused it.

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    webView.onResume()
}


override fun onDestroy() {
    webView.onPause()
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

Hey, I can accept that given answers for onPause are working but I had an issue with it. I have Interstitial ad in my app and calling `webView.onPause()` in onPause make the interstitial ad unclickable. (Because activity going on resume and ad losing focus).

I am sharing this for those who have same issue.