# Phonegap - Video doesn't toggle to fullscreen in the inappbrowser

Tags: html5-video, cordova-plugins, fullscreen, phonegap, inappbrowser

I have an app that opens links in inappbrowser. Some of those links have videos along with some text. On ios, those videos play and when pressed fullscreen option, they play in fullscreen. However on android, those videos play but no matter how many times I press the fullscreen option on the video, the video never plays on the fullscreen. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54266761/1269722). I think Phonegap uses the same plugin as Cordova. However, I'm not sure about the process on how to use a customized version.