# Android WebView video closes immedietly after being set to fullscreen

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to play fullscreen videos in WebView but when I press to open fullscreen it closes and goes back to its original view. It does go fullscreen but only after several attempts.

It works on old devices I tested on but on Nougat it does what I explained above.

[This](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromium-webview-samples/blob/master/fullscreen-video-sample/app/src/main/java/fullscreenvideosample/android/chrome/google/com/fullscreenvideosample/MainActivity.java) is what I tried

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview) but it did the same thing

I really appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: I haz the same problem. Plz help :O :O :O

Comment: Did you find out more about this problem?

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything unfortunately not, I've kind of side benched it for now

Comment: Ah i see i see, no problem. I have implemented another solution. Using Chrome custom tabs now.

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything gl :) I'll notify you if I come back and figure it out