# WebView Youtube Fullscreen mode

Tags: android, webview, youtube, android-webview

I have my WebView where I go to Youtube and if the user touch on Fullscreen button I want to rotate my device to landscape mode. Have anyone faced with this? 
Thanx all in advance fir any help!

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question...

this question can help you...

[Playing HTML5 video on fullscreen in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview)

or if you already done this... you just need to do one thing is, to get the event when user click on fullscreen mode.

**then simply**

You can set the screen orientation programatically anytime you want using:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: I know about these methods but my question is how to handle this event, when user taps on full screen button.