# How to enable fullscreen button while playing video in Android webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have one site and the site is responsive. I used `WebView` to create an app for my site. Everything is OK but when play videos of my site Full-Screen button is disabled, how I can solve this problem thanks

and my activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState )
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    webView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

[this pic for better help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgphQ.jpg)

Comment: Refer this link : https://www.monstertechnocodes.com/2018/07/how-to-enable-fullscreen-mode-in-any.html

Comment: This answer can help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview/16179544#16179544