# Android WebView video fullscreen mode not working

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I look for this famous solution [Playing HTML5 video on fullscreen in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview). But even their own project is not working while I run it to my device(Nougat). Youtube videos are not go to fullscreen while clicking on that square box to go to fullscreen. What can I do in farther?

Answer (score 0):

use link below for showing video in android:

[ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer)

Comment: Can ExoPlayer play youtube videos too?

Comment: yes, use this link . https://androidwave.com/play-youtube-video-in-exoplayer/

Comment: Actually what I want is to be like browser, not for a spicific link. I want users to browse the site youtube and when they select a video, it will play with ExoPlayer. Is it possible? Thank you.