# Vimeo video fullscreen button not showing in android webview. Can you please help me?

Tags: android, iframe, webview

Vimeo video fullscreen button not showing in android webview. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android webview is limited in its support of HTML5 Videos

Use this instead

https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView

[Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16179544/13533028)