# Android compose webview not showing full screen video

Tags: android, youtube, android-jetpack-compose

How to make the video open in full screen? In webview, when you press a button in YouTube to full screen, the video does not open in full screen, pressing is ignored:

```
val initialUrl = currentUrl?.value
            val lastUrl by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }
            val url = lastUrl ?: initialUrl
            val state = url?.let { rememberWebViewState(url = it) }
            if (state != null) {
                val webViewState = rememberSaveableWebViewState()
                val navigator = rememberWebViewNavigator()
                LaunchedEffect(navigator) {
                    val bundle = webViewState.viewState
                    if (bundle == null) {
                        currentUrl?.value?.let { navigator.loadUrl(it) }
                    }
                }
                WebView(
                    state = webViewState,
                    navigator = navigator,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    onCreated = {
                        it.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                        it.settings.allowFileAccess = true
                        it.settings.allowContentAccess = true
                        it.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
                        it.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
                        it.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
                        it.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
                        it.settings.userAgentString = System.getProperty("http.agent")
                    }
                )
            }`
```

I tried to add different settings to the webview, but they do not work, I also added android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" to the manifest

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/15768837/150978

Comment: this is not the answer to my question