# Supporing video tag in html5 on Honeycomb

Tags: android, html5-video

I've got problem with supporting video tag. On Gingerbread [WebView and HTML5 <video>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video) this works great, but on Honeycomb, method `onShowCustomView` is never fired like on Gingerbread.

I noticed that webview is trying to use AwesomePlayer, I guess this is default wideo player for 3.x, but how can I prevent from using that player and replace it with my own implementation?

Maybe there is another solution for that?

My websettings:

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + MainActivity.class.getPackage().getName() + "/databases");
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
```

Whole log from ddms while clicking on video:

```
08-13 15:17:31.680: DEBUG/GPS(310): sv_status_cb : (num_svs : 3, num_of_used_view : 0)
08-13 15:17:32.530: DEBUG/HierarchicalStateMachine(310): handleMessage: E msg.what=83
08-13 15:17:32.530: DEBUG/HierarchicalStateMachine(310): processMsg: ConnectedState
08-13 15:17:32.530: DEBUG/WifiStateMachine(310): ConnectedState{ what=83 when=-4ms arg1=65 }
08-13 15:17:32.550: DEBUG/HierarchicalStateMachine(310): handleMessage: X
08-13 15:17:32.680: DEBUG/GPS(310): sv_status_cb : (num_svs : 3, num_of_used_view : 0)
08-13 15:17:33.690: DEBUG/GPS(310): sv_status_cb : (num_svs : 3, num_of_used_view : 0)
08-13 15:17:33.730: INFO/InputReader(310): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0, pending(waiting finished signal)=0
08-13 15:17:33.730: INFO/InputDispatcher(310): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '419d6628 pl.app/pl.app.activity.DetalActivity (server)'
08-13 15:17:33.730: INFO/InputDispatcher(310): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel 'TouchIntercepter (server)'
08-13 15:17:33.730: INFO/System.out(23756): addPressedID already exists: 0
08-13 15:17:33.820: INFO/InputReader(310): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1, pending(waiting finished signal)=0
08-13 15:17:33.820: INFO/InputDispatcher(310): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '419d6628 pl.app/pl.app.activity.DetalActivity (server)'
08-13 15:17:33.820: INFO/InputDispatcher(310): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel 'TouchIntercepter (server)'
08-13 15:17:33.820: VERBOSE/webview(23756):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
08-13 15:17:33.850: DEBUG/dalvikvm(23070): GC_EXPLICIT freed 27K, 5% free 6216K/6531K, paused 6ms+2ms
08-13 15:17:33.860: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): nativeDraw called here 
08-13 15:17:33.860: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): PictureSet* draw called here 
08-13 15:17:33.870: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): drawContentComposition*  called here 
08-13 15:17:33.870: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): *****drawContentComposition******* -  ENTER
08-13 15:17:33.870: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-13 15:17:33.880: DEBUG/InputManagerService(310): startInputLocked: cs=ClientState{41953a10 uid 10099 pid 23756}, cs.pid=23756, Binding.getCallingPid()=310
08-13 15:17:33.880: INFO/WindowManager(310): Putting input method here!
08-13 15:17:33.880: DEBUG/WindowManager(310): Desired input method target: Window{419d6628 pl.app/pl.app.activity.DetalActivity paused=false}
08-13 15:17:33.880: DEBUG/WindowManager(310): Current focus: Window{419d6628 pl.app/pl.app.activity.DetalActivity paused=false}
08-13 15:17:33.880: DEBUG/WindowManager(310): Last focus: Window{419d6628 pl.app/pl.app.activity.DetalActivity paused=false}
08-13 15:17:33.880: DEBUG/WindowManager(310): IM target client: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41cb9298
08-13 15:17:33.880: DEBUG/WindowManager(310): IM target client binder: android.os.BinderProxy@419b9008
08-13 15:17:33.880: DEBUG/WindowManager(310): Requesting client binder: android.os.BinderProxy@419b9008
08-13 15:17:33.880: DEBUG/WindowManager(310):     w.mAttrs.token=ActivityRecord{416faab0 pl.app/.activity.DetalActivity}
08-13 15:17:33.880: DEBUG/WindowManager(310):     w.mToken=AppWindowToken{41fd2068 token=ActivityRecord{416faab0 pl.app/.activity.DetalActivity}}
08-13 15:17:33.880: DEBUG/WindowManager(310):     token=AppWindowToken{41fd2068 token=ActivityRecord{416faab0 pl.app/.activity.DetalActivity}}
08-13 15:17:33.880: INFO/WindowManager(310): Placing input method @4
08-13 15:17:33.940: DEBUG/CLIPBOARD(310): Hide Clipboard dialog inside hideSoftInput() !
08-13 15:17:33.940: DEBUG/CLIPBOARD(310): Hide Clipboard dialog inside hideSoftInput() !
08-13 15:17:33.960: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): nativeDraw called here 
08-13 15:17:33.960: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): PictureSet* draw called here 
08-13 15:17:33.970: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): drawContentComposition*  called here 
08-13 15:17:33.970: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): *****drawContentComposition******* -  ENTER
08-13 15:17:33.970: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-13 15:17:33.970: ERROR/libEGL(23756): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
08-13 15:17:33.970: DEBUG/ShaderProgram(23756): couldn't load the vertex shader!
08-13 15:17:33.970: ERROR/libEGL(23756): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
08-13 15:17:33.970: DEBUG/ShaderProgram(23756): couldn't load the vertex shader!
08-13 15:17:33.970: ERROR/libEGL(23756): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
08-13 15:17:33.970: DEBUG/ShaderProgram(23756): couldn't load the vertex shader!
08-13 15:17:33.970: ERROR/libEGL(23756): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
08-13 15:17:33.970: DEBUG/ShaderProgram(23756): couldn't load the vertex shader!
08-13 15:17:33.970: ERROR/libEGL(23756): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
08-13 15:17:33.970: DEBUG/ShaderProgram(23756): couldn't load the vertex shader!
08-13 15:17:33.970: ERROR/libEGL(23756): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
08-13 15:17:33.970: DEBUG/ShaderProgram(23756): couldn't load the vertex shader!
08-13 15:17:33.980: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): calling drawContentComposition 
08-13 15:17:33.980: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): *****drawContentComposition******* -  ENTER
08-13 15:17:33.980: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-13 15:17:34.000: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): nativeDraw called here 
08-13 15:17:34.000: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): PictureSet* draw called here 
08-13 15:17:34.010: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): drawContentComposition*  called here 
08-13 15:17:34.010: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): *****drawContentComposition******* -  ENTER
08-13 15:17:34.010: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-13 15:17:34.010: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): calling drawContentComposition 
08-13 15:17:34.010: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): *****drawContentComposition******* -  ENTER
08-13 15:17:34.010: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-13 15:17:34.030: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): nativeDraw called here 
08-13 15:17:34.030: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): PictureSet* draw called here 
08-13 15:17:34.040: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): drawContentComposition*  called here 
08-13 15:17:34.040: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): *****drawContentComposition******* -  ENTER
08-13 15:17:34.040: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-13 15:17:34.040: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): calling drawContentComposition 
08-13 15:17:34.040: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): *****drawContentComposition******* -  ENTER
08-13 15:17:34.040: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-13 15:17:34.370: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): nativeDraw called here 
08-13 15:17:34.370: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): PictureSet* draw called here 
08-13 15:17:34.370: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): drawContentComposition*  called here 
08-13 15:17:34.370: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): *****drawContentComposition******* -  ENTER
08-13 15:17:34.370: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-13 15:17:34.370: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): calling drawContentComposition 
08-13 15:17:34.370: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): *****drawContentComposition******* -  ENTER
08-13 15:17:34.370: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-13 15:17:34.680: DEBUG/GPS(310): sv_status_cb : (num_svs : 3, num_of_used_view : 0)
08-13 15:17:34.760: ERROR/libEGL(23756): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
08-13 15:17:34.760: INFO/MediaPlayer(23756): prepareAsync called in state 4
08-13 15:17:34.770: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): Adding $Version, 0
08-13 15:17:34.770: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): HTTP url http://www.somevideo.tv/_mv/EQVjPjfnao.s.mp4
08-13 15:17:34.770: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): connect to www.somevideo.tv:80/_mv/EQVjPjfnao.s.mp4 @0
08-13 15:17:34.770: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): 1'th connecting...
08-13 15:17:34.770: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): connect_l (@0) to www.somevideo.tv:80/_mv/EQVjPjfnao.s.mp4
08-13 15:17:34.770: ERROR/HTTPStream(31914): Connect to www.somevideo.tv:80 Https (0)
08-13 15:17:34.790: INFO/HTTPStream(31914): GetAddrInfo new address. (Cache) : www.somevideo.tv
08-13 15:17:34.810: INFO/HTTPStream(31914): eth0 IP Address : 192.168.1.105
08-13 15:17:34.850: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): Before Cookies catch
08-13 15:17:34.850: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): After Cookies catch
08-13 15:17:34.850: ERROR/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): Redirect Status Code.
08-13 15:17:34.850: ERROR/HTTPStream(31914): disconnect - shutdown after 
08-13 15:17:34.850: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): HTTP url http://media.somevideo.pl/_mv/EQVjPjfnao.s.mp4
08-13 15:17:34.850: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): connect to media.somevideo.pl:80/_mv/EQVjPjfnao.s.mp4 @0
08-13 15:17:34.850: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): 1'th connecting...
08-13 15:17:34.850: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): connect_l (@0) to media.somevideo.pl:80/_mv/EQVjPjfnao.s.mp4
08-13 15:17:34.850: ERROR/HTTPStream(31914): Connect to media.somevideo.pl:80 Https (0)
08-13 15:17:34.870: INFO/HTTPStream(31914): GetAddrInfo new address. (Cache) : media.somevideo.pl
08-13 15:17:34.890: INFO/HTTPStream(31914): eth0 IP Address : 192.168.1.105
08-13 15:17:34.970: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): Before Cookies catch
08-13 15:17:34.970: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): After Cookies catch
08-13 15:17:34.970: ERROR/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): Redirect Status Code.
08-13 15:17:34.970: ERROR/HTTPStream(31914): disconnect - shutdown after 
08-13 15:17:34.970: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): HTTP url http://192.168.1.101/suso/?host=rsomevideotv07a.mm.somevideo.pl&file=fa3df22bcd2294f4c184d30bbc79f5bc,11,5274564&type=video/mp4&clid=1&rt=1&ri=1641131&mi=64&st=Z6CsakA91FRTJ8tDrs6LYQ&e=1313242357
08-13 15:17:34.970: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): connect to 192.168.1.101:80/suso/?host=rsomevideotv07a.mm.somevideo.pl&file=fa3df22bcd2294f4c184d30bbc79f5bc,11,5274564&type=video/mp4&clid=1&rt=1&ri=1641131&mi=64&st=Z6CsakA91FRTJ8tDrs6LYQ&e=1313242357 @0
08-13 15:17:34.970: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): 1'th connecting...
08-13 15:17:34.970: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): connect_l (@0) to 192.168.1.101:80/suso/?host=rsomevideotv07a.mm.somevideo.pl&file=fa3df22bcd2294f4c184d30bbc79f5bc,11,5274564&type=video/mp4&clid=1&rt=1&ri=1641131&mi=64&st=Z6CsakA91FRTJ8tDrs6LYQ&e=1313242357
08-13 15:17:34.970: ERROR/HTTPStream(31914): Connect to 192.168.1.101:80 Https (0)
08-13 15:17:34.970: INFO/HTTPStream(31914): GetAddrInfo new address. (Cache) : 192.168.1.101
08-13 15:17:34.990: INFO/HTTPStream(31914): eth0 IP Address : 192.168.1.105
08-13 15:17:35.120: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): Before Cookies catch
08-13 15:17:35.120: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): After Cookies catch
08-13 15:17:35.120: ERROR/NuCachedSource2(31914): calling NuCachedSource2
08-13 15:17:35.120: WARN/NuCachedSource2(31914):  bitrate - 0kbps, LowWater Mark - 4096K, High Water Mark - 20480K, sleep = 0sec
08-13 15:17:35.330: ERROR/MediaExtractor(31914): **********MediaExtractor::Create
08-13 15:17:35.330: DEBUG/DivXPlugin(226): DivXPlugin::onInitialize : 63
08-13 15:17:35.330: DEBUG/DivXPlugin(226): DivXPlugin::onSetOnInfoListener : 63
08-13 15:17:35.330: DEBUG/DivXPlugin(226): DivXPlugin::onOpenDecryptSession: Enter : 63
08-13 15:17:35.330: ERROR/DivXPlugin(226): DivXPlugin::onOpenDecryptSession() Not a Divx File.
08-13 15:17:35.550: DEBUG/HierarchicalStateMachine(310): handleMessage: E msg.what=83
08-13 15:17:35.550: DEBUG/HierarchicalStateMachine(310): processMsg: ConnectedState
08-13 15:17:35.550: DEBUG/WifiStateMachine(310): ConnectedState{ what=83 when=-4ms arg1=65 }
08-13 15:17:35.560: DEBUG/HierarchicalStateMachine(310): handleMessage: X
08-13 15:17:35.570: ERROR/DrmManager(Native)(226): DrmManager::openDecryptSession: no capable plug-in found
08-13 15:17:35.570: DEBUG/DivXPlugin(226): DivXPlugin::onTerminate : 63
08-13 15:17:35.580: ERROR/MediaExtractor(31914): ************Autodetected media content as 'video/mpeg4' with confidence 0.40
08-13 15:17:35.580: INFO/SampleTable(31914): There are reordered frames present.
08-13 15:17:35.590: INFO/OMXCodec(31914): [OMX.Nvidia.h264.decode] AVC profile = 100 (High), level = 30
08-13 15:17:35.590: INFO/OMXCodec(31914): [OMX.Nvidia.h264.decode] allocating 10 buffers of size 1566720 on input port
08-13 15:17:35.590: INFO/OMXCodec(31914): [OMX.Nvidia.h264.decode] allocating 10 buffers from a native window of size 345600 on output port
08-13 15:17:35.600: INFO/nvos_linux_stub(31914): stub_helper: alloc iovmm
08-13 15:17:35.660: INFO/nvos_linux_stub(31914): stub_helper: alloc carveout_iram
08-13 15:17:35.680: DEBUG/GPS(310): sv_status_cb : (num_svs : 3, num_of_used_view : 0)
08-13 15:17:35.700: INFO/nvos_linux_stub(31914): NvMMVideoDecoderH264SetAttribute@797: info=2147483647 DeintType = 2147483647, DeintRate = 2
08-13 15:17:35.710: INFO/OMXCodec(31914): [OMX.SEC.aac.dec] allocating 5 buffers of size 13824 on input port
08-13 15:17:35.710: INFO/OMXCodec(31914): [OMX.SEC.aac.dec] allocating 9 buffers of size 8192 on output port
08-13 15:17:35.750: VERBOSE/(23756): In ResourceHandle::create newHandle
08-13 15:17:35.750: VERBOSE/(23756): In ResourceHandle::create newHandle the url is = http://m.somevideo.pl/_m/,21,1.jpg
08-13 15:17:35.790: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): nativeDraw called here 
08-13 15:17:35.790: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): PictureSet* draw called here 
08-13 15:17:35.800: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): drawContentComposition*  called here 
08-13 15:17:35.800: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): *****drawContentComposition******* -  ENTER
08-13 15:17:35.810: DEBUG/CONTEXT(23756): m_mainFrame->editor()->hasComposition not 
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/NuHTTPDataSource(31914): AVE NW bps (during 0s): 15458Kbps
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(31914): [66] getDuration = 167840
08-13 15:17:36.680: DEBUG/GPS(310): sv_status_cb : (num_svs : 3, num_of_used_view : 0)
08-13 15:17:37.680: DEBUG/GPS(310): sv_status_cb : (num_svs : 3, num_of_used_view : 0)
```

And log filter only to awesomePlayer

```
08-13 15:17:34.760: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): setDefault
08-13 15:17:34.760: ERROR/AwesomePlayer(31914): calling AwesomePlayer
08-13 15:17:34.760: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): setDefault
08-13 15:17:34.760: ERROR/AwesomePlayer(31914): calling reset
08-13 15:17:34.760: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): reset_l
08-13 15:17:34.760: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): cancelPlayerEvents (keepBufferingGoing=0)
08-13 15:17:34.760: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): reset done
08-13 15:17:34.760: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): setListener
08-13 15:17:34.760: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): setAudioSink
08-13 15:17:34.760: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): setDataSource (http://www.somevideo.tv/_mv/EQVjPjfnao.s.mp4)
08-13 15:17:34.760: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): setDataSource_l
08-13 15:17:34.760: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): reset_l
08-13 15:17:34.760: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): cancelPlayerEvents (keepBufferingGoing=0)
08-13 15:17:34.760: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): setDefault
08-13 15:17:34.760: INFO/AwesomePlayer(31914): setDataSource_l('http://www.somevideo.tv/_mv/EQVjPjfnao.s.mp4')
08-13 15:17:34.760: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): setSurfaceTexture
08-13 15:17:34.760: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): prepareAsync
08-13 15:17:34.760: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): prepareAsync_l
08-13 15:17:34.770: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): onPrepareAsyncEvent
08-13 15:17:34.770: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): finishSetDataSource_l
08-13 15:17:35.580: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): finishSetDataSource_l getDrmInfo
08-13 15:17:35.580: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): setDataSource_l
08-13 15:17:35.590: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): setVideoSource
08-13 15:17:35.590: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): setAudioSource
08-13 15:17:35.590: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): initVideoDecoder
08-13 15:17:35.590: INFO/AwesomePlayer(31914): Video duration : 167840000
08-13 15:17:35.700: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): initAudioDecoder
08-13 15:17:35.720: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): postBufferingEvent_l
08-13 15:17:35.780: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): isPlaying
08-13 15:17:35.810: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): isPlaying
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): onBufferingUpdate
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:35.820: ERROR/AwesomePlayer(31914):  cached size =1179648, Final Status = 0
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getCachedAmountPercentage
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getPosition
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): positionUs = mVideoTimeUs
08-13 15:17:35.820: INFO/AwesomePlayer(31914): getPosition : 0
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getTimeForOffset
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): notifyListener_l
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getCachedDuration_l
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): finishAsyncPrepare_l
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): notifyVideoSize_l
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): notifyListener_l
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): notifyListener_l
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): postBufferingEvent_l
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getDuration
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getDuration (167840000)
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): calling seekTo  time us (0)
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getPosition
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): positionUs = mVideoTimeUs
08-13 15:17:35.820: INFO/AwesomePlayer(31914): getPosition : 0
08-13 15:17:35.820: INFO/AwesomePlayer(31914): seekTo, locked=1
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): seekTo
08-13 15:17:35.820: ERROR/AwesomePlayer(31914): calling seekTo_l
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): seekAudioIfNecessary_l
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): notifyListener_l
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): setLooping
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): setLooping (0)
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): setLooping
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): setLooping (0)
08-13 15:17:35.820: ERROR/AwesomePlayer(31914): calling play
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): play
08-13 15:17:35.820: ERROR/AwesomePlayer(31914): calling play_l
08-13 15:17:35.820: INFO/AwesomePlayer(31914): Not a drm file dude!!!
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): seekAudioIfNecessary_l
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): addBatteryData
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): isPlaying
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): isPlaying
08-13 15:17:35.820: ERROR/AwesomePlayer(31914): calling pause
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): pause
08-13 15:17:35.820: ERROR/AwesomePlayer(31914): calling pause_l
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): cancelPlayerEvents (keepBufferingGoing=1)
08-13 15:17:35.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): addBatteryData
08-13 15:17:36.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): onBufferingUpdate
08-13 15:17:36.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:36.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): notifyListener_l
08-13 15:17:36.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getCachedDuration_l
08-13 15:17:36.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:36.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): postBufferingEvent_l
08-13 15:17:37.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): onBufferingUpdate
08-13 15:17:37.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:37.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getCachedAmountPercentage
08-13 15:17:37.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getPosition
08-13 15:17:37.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): positionUs = mSeekTimeUs
08-13 15:17:37.820: INFO/AwesomePlayer(31914): getPosition : 0
08-13 15:17:37.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getTimeForOffset
08-13 15:17:37.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): notifyListener_l
08-13 15:17:37.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getCachedDuration_l
08-13 15:17:37.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:37.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): postBufferingEvent_l
08-13 15:17:38.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): onBufferingUpdate
08-13 15:17:38.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:38.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): notifyListener_l
08-13 15:17:38.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getCachedDuration_l
08-13 15:17:38.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:38.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): postBufferingEvent_l
08-13 15:17:39.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): onBufferingUpdate
08-13 15:17:39.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:39.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getCachedAmountPercentage
08-13 15:17:39.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getPosition
08-13 15:17:39.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): positionUs = mSeekTimeUs
08-13 15:17:39.820: INFO/AwesomePlayer(31914): getPosition : 0
08-13 15:17:39.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getTimeForOffset
08-13 15:17:39.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): notifyListener_l
08-13 15:17:39.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getCachedDuration_l
08-13 15:17:39.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:39.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): postBufferingEvent_l
08-13 15:17:40.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): onBufferingUpdate
08-13 15:17:40.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:40.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): notifyListener_l
08-13 15:17:40.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getCachedDuration_l
08-13 15:17:40.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:40.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): postBufferingEvent_l
08-13 15:17:41.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): onBufferingUpdate
08-13 15:17:41.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:41.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getCachedAmountPercentage
08-13 15:17:41.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getPosition
08-13 15:17:41.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): positionUs = mSeekTimeUs
08-13 15:17:41.820: INFO/AwesomePlayer(31914): getPosition : 0
08-13 15:17:41.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getTimeForOffset
08-13 15:17:41.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): notifyListener_l
08-13 15:17:41.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getCachedDuration_l
08-13 15:17:41.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:41.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): postBufferingEvent_l
08-13 15:17:42.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): onBufferingUpdate
08-13 15:17:42.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:42.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): notifyListener_l
08-13 15:17:42.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getCachedDuration_l
08-13 15:17:42.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:42.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): postBufferingEvent_l
08-13 15:17:43.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): onBufferingUpdate
08-13 15:17:43.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:43.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getCachedAmountPercentage
08-13 15:17:43.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getPosition
08-13 15:17:43.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): positionUs = mSeekTimeUs
08-13 15:17:43.820: INFO/AwesomePlayer(31914): getPosition : 0
08-13 15:17:43.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getTimeForOffset
08-13 15:17:43.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): notifyListener_l
08-13 15:17:43.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getCachedDuration_l
08-13 15:17:43.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): getBitrate
08-13 15:17:43.820: DEBUG/AwesomePlayer(31914): postBufferingEvent_l
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?  Are the hacks required in 2.x also required in 3.x?

Comment: Not really, I used reflection to get url from that callback, then I open custom VideoView using that url. Which is awful, but it's displayed fullscreen ;)