# Does Android WebView support html5?

Tags: android, html, webview

Does Android WebView support html5? Especial the video tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebView and HTML5 <video>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Just check out slides for HTML5WebView.

http://www.tandroid.org/html5webview

and also check this SO answer..

[WebView and HTML5 <video>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video/3882736#3882736)

Comment: It would have been better if you could give an actual answer WITH the supporting links, instead of just posting the links.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you should use:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(WebChromeClient())
```

And add the following attribute in your manifest within the activity tag:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

For more information, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17260005/6046829)