# Android : html video works on phone but not on android TV

Tags: android, android-webview, html5-video, android-tv

I have an app that play html5 videos on an html page, it works just fine but when I test my app on android TV, it makes my apps crash...
Does webview use something special to display video that android TV doesn't have ?

I'm on API 21 by the way

Comment: Be noted of the supported [Video formats and codecs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html#video-formats). Example, for `H.265 HEVC` format, it should be Main Profile Level 3 for mobile devices and Main Profile Level 4.1 for Android TV. Here's another reference which might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273046/android-webview-video-autoplay-success-but-same-apk-fails-on-android-tv-mini-pc?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @abielita You seems to understand videos more than me, I downloaded <a href="https://mediaarea.net/fr/MediaInfo">mediainfo</a> and saw that my format profil is "Main@L3.1" but I can't seems to find something like H.2XX ... Do you know where I can find this ?

Comment: @abielita From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627873/cant-play-video-in-android-uploded-from-iphone) it says : _If your content is intended solely for iPad, Apple TV, iPhone 4 and later, and Mac OS X computers, you should use Main Level 3.1._ so my video should be supported I think