# React Native Android Webview Video

Tags: javascript, android, video, webview, react-native

I'm using React Native to create an Android/iOS app and trying to get a video to play in the WebView component. The video plays fine on iOS, but I'm having trouble getting it to play in the android WebView.

I've come across a few threads like this one ([Enabling HTML5 video playback in android WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259636/enabling-html5-video-playback-in-android-webview)) that claim this is a fairly common problem on Android and can be solved by importing WebChromeClient and setting that option on the webview like so:

```
mainWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

But almost all these threads are strictly about building a native Android app and not using React Native.

Does anyone know how to get this to work in React Native?

Comment: have you tried this plugin https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-video

Comment: Yea, that's slightly different than what I'm looking for. I'm looking to display an embed link from and online video player inside a webview so that I can use their web player and all the functionality they've built into it (roll back 30 seconds, full screen, etc). React-native-video is just a component that allows you to play the video, but would require me to link directly to the source as well as recreate all the UI for the player. I might end up doing that if I can't solve this though. Thanks though!

Comment: do you have vsn .27? it supports android.. http://facebook.github.io/react-native/

Comment: Yea, I'm using .27. The webview itself works fine. It's just trying to play HTML5 video in it that breaks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, have you ever gotten this to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I refer to an [article by Yevgen Safronov](https://medium.com/@sejoker/writing-android-component-for-react-native-e34802bf3377#.4w5m377ro)

In it, he writes

> Obviously the most challenging part of the application is handling
>   live video stream, because it requires switching stream’s video
>   quality based on available Internet bandwidth. But first things
>   first — I needed a RN native component to show any video stream. There
>   is a popular video component for RN but it has support for iOS only. I
>   decided to write my own RN component wrapper around Vitamio player. It
>   is well known open-source project and has support of RTMP protocol we
>   use for mobile app.
>
> I had no prior experience with writing native RN components so I went
>   directly to RN documentation on how to create one. A guide I refer to
>   is called Native UI Components, there is similar one for iOS. There
>   are several essential parts to declare:
>
> Implement custom ViewManager (Android part)
>   Register the ViewManager (Android part)
>   Implement the JavaScript module
>   Register the module (Android part)
>
> Implement custom ViewManager Referring to the example of declaring
>   VideoView for Vitamio this is how the essence of VideoView declaration
>   looks like:

```
public class VideoViewDemo extends Activity {
 @Override public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
   super.onCreate(icicle);
   if (!LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
     return;
   setContentView(R.layout.videoview);
   mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url);
   mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
   if (path == "") { return; }
   mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
   mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
   mVideoView.requestFocus();
 }
...
}
```

> The code looks quite straightforward. Apart from passing a reference
>   to Activity into LibsChecker, VideoView requires a path to a video
>   stream and instance of MediaController.

```
public class VitamioViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<VideoView>{ 
 public static final String REACT_CLASS = “RCTVitamioView”;
 @Override
 public String getName() {
   return REACT_CLASS;
 }
```

expose setStreamUrl setter using ReactProp:

```
@ReactProp(name = "streamUrl")
public void setStreamUrl(VideoView view, @Nullable String streamUrl) {
   if (!LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(mActivity))
      return;

   view.setVideoPath(streamUrl);       
   view.setMediaController(new MediaController(mContext));
   view.requestFocus();       
}
```

add createViewInstance implementation:

```
private ThemedReactContext mContext = null;
private Activity mActivity = null;
@Override
public VideoView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context){
  mContext = context;   
  return new VideoView(context);
}
One note about the code. Because LibsChecker requires an instance of Activity we will receive it via constructor, it will reference root activity used for RN application;
public VitamioViewManager(Activity activity) {
  mActivity = activity;
}
```

Register the ViewManager
The final Java step is to register the ViewManager to the application, this happens via the applications package member function createViewManagers:
...

```
public class VitamioViewPackage implements ReactPackage {

  private Activity mActivity = null;

  public VitamioViewPackage(Activity activity) {
      mActivity = activity;
  }


  @Override    
  public List<NativeModule>
  createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
     return Collections.emptyList();
  }  
  @Override
  public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }     
  @Override
  public List<ViewManager>
  createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(
      new VitamioViewManager(mActivity)
    );    
  }
}
```

> Implement the JavaScript module In order to expose custom UI component
>   in JavaScript it is necessary to call special requireNativeComponent
>   function:

```
var { requireNativeComponent, PropTypes } = require('react-native');

var iface = {
  name: 'VideoView',
  propTypes: {
    streamUrl: PropTypes.string
  }
};

module.exports = requireNativeComponent('RCTVitamioView', iface);
```

> Register the module Although it’s not mentioned as required step in
>   official documentation we need it because of reference to the root
>   activity: package com.vitamio_demo;

```
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.sejoker.VitamView.VitamioViewPackage; // <--- import

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "vitamio_demo";
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether dev mode should be enabled.
     * This enables e.g. the dev menu.
     */
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

   /**
   * A list of packages used by the app. If the app uses additional views
   * or modules besides the default ones, add more packages here.
   */
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new MainReactPackage(),
        new VitamioViewPackage(this)          // <------ add here
      );
    }
}
```

> Example of usage
>   Install the package in a project:

```
npm i react-native-android-vitamio --save
```

> DeclareVideoView:

```
var VitamioView = require('react-native-android-vitamio');

class VideoScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <VitamioView style={styles.video} streamUrl="rtmp://fms.12E5.edgecastcdn.net/0012E5/mp4:videos/8Juv1MVa-485.mp4"/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  video: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      height: 400,
    }
})

module.exports = VideoScreen;
```

Hope this is of help, A list of his own references is given in the article.