# how to play videos on a native mobile application?

Tags: android, mobile, jquery-mobile, html5-video, flash-cs5.5

I'm trying to embed a video on a native mobile application(android). I'm using dreamweaver cs5.5. when I tested it on a browser, it works. but when i compiled it as an .apk, the video is not playing.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>VIDEO</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" controls="controls" >      
        <object style="margin-left:0px;margin-top:10px;" id="video" width="296" height="222" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/R6Z7xceSLy4" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="autoplay" value="true">
    <param name="autoStart" value="0">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/R6Z7xceSLy4" />
</object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

playing video like this doesnt work in android webview currently, which phonegap uses. this  might help. [WebView and HTML5 <video>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video)