# Android embedded HTML5 video

Tags: android, html, video, android-webview

I have an embedded html file in my file system, it works fine if I drag n drop the file to

> assets/index.html

and I have tested the HTML5 video playback [from here](http://www.tandroid.org/html5webview). Works fine.

Now, if I want to show an embedded page with HTML5 video [working on browser] as an embedded file, just by changing the sample code for the [HTML5 android webView player](http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/) and drag n drop the index.html in assets for this project, it doesn't work, the app crashes with this error:

> sorry, the app * has stopped unexpectedly...

so I just change

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://freebsd.csie.nctu.edu.tw/~freedom/html5/");
```

to

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

It doesn't work.

What am I missing, is there a basic example of HTML5 video embedded?

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video

Comment: Quite an old question with a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `index.html` in `assets/www/index.html` and change `mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");` to `mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [loadDataWithBaseURL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String baseUrl = shouldUseCachedFiles ? "file:///android_asset/"
                        :mUrl;
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, htmlContent, "text/html",
                        "utf-8", baseUrl);
```

where the htmlContent is retrieved with an AsynchTask and loaded into the webView.