# HTML5 Video in WebView in ICS

Tags: android, video, webview, html5-video

The old trick [WebView and HTML5 <video>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video) works great until Android 3+. The problem with ICS is the video can play both inline and fullscreen, but when I lock the screen, the video will continue play at the background (I can hear the voice).

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Try this in your code, I think this is how I fixed the problem :

```
public void onPause() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        super.onPause();
    }
}

public void onResume() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dongshengcn since this is some old question, Did you find any solution. get the same issue here

Comment: yeah, I will edit the original post to include the answers.