# HTML5 video events not triggered

Tags: android, video

I used the advice here: [WebView and HTML5 <video>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video)

To show a video in a webview by overriding onShowCustomView and setting the videoView the activity content.

In the js there is an event listener on the video element waiting for the "ended" event. This event never gets thrown and so the actions (eg, go to next page) that are meant to happen at the end of the video never occur.

As far as I can tell I don't have access to the js video element and so can't manually throw the event by overring onCompletion in Android code.

Is there a way to fix this without making changes to the js as it is not certain that I will always have access to this.

Thanks

KK

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with GingerBread.
Tried on several devices and 2.0- <2.3 it worked fine.
In the end I pass a custom event in onCompletion via a js bridge up to the js page and handle both the custom end event and the normal end event in the same way.

KK