# Unclear error when playing a video in a VideoView

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I'm trying to play a video (by a uri) in a VideoView and sometimes get the following errors:

> E/MediaPlayer(15861): error (1, -2147483648)
>   D/MediaPlayer(15861): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
>   W/MediaPlayer(15861): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events

I found that the "list" of codes can be found in the following source code:
https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h
(thanks to the thread [Complete list of MediaPlayer error codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046753/complete-list-of-mediaplayer-error-codes))

But that does not make things more clear, there's nothing there about -2147483648, and the 1 I get is positive and in this source it says that error codes are negative.

Same thing was reported in this thread: [Playing youtube video in a videoview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929871/playing-youtube-video-in-a-videoview), though he did not ask about what this error means (nor did he get any helping answer).

Anyone has an idea of the meaning of this error?
Thanks.

---

Edit

I'm trying to show youtube videos, the url of the stream is taken from http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=VIDEO_ID and it's being done asynchronously.
When the result gets back, this is the code I'm using:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        setVideoURI(videoStream);
    }
});
```

This is being executed by a class which extends VideoView.

Comment: Do you have the official twitter app installed? If so try removing and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Twitter? I don't see how that's relevant. No, I don't have a twitter app installed.

Answer (score 0):

1 stand for  `MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN`. and -2147483648 is a myth
 
Refer to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN) for further details.
This kind of error occurs when trying to play an invalid url. Assuming you are not using third party libraries.

Comment: Thanks for that reference, but what makes a url to be invalid? And how is it that the same exact url can work just fine one time and then produce this kind of error on a 2nd try?

Comment: Is your connection stable? Is your server stable? If you can post some code maybe we could help. I am familiar with this error. And I am assuming you are not using third party libs.