# Seeking forward in YouTube HTML5 video over Android WebView

Tags: android, html, video, youtube

> **EDIT** Nevermind, YouTube released the Native Android API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

I have an application that shows an HTML5 videoview over a WebView. This video is forced to be HTML5 from YouTube service (http://www.youtube.com/embed/3FFyT039tJ0?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&html5=1&start=90&end=176
)

As you can see in the URL, the parameter "start" shows the number of seconds the video must start playing at. I have been using the method `onShowCustomView` of `WebChromeClient` to obtain the `VideoView` object created by the WebView, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video).

When I have the reference to the `VideoView`, I can use the method `seekTo()` to accomplish my goal. Till here everything is fine, but only for Android versions lower than 4.x.

As many of you know, the method `onShowCustomView` of `WebViewChromeClient`, from 4.x and forward, is only called when user clicks on "FullScreen" mode, but not when the video starts playing (how used to be before 4.x).

So, the point is that I can't seek 90 seconds forward because I can't obtain the reference to the VideoView, and I can't find any workaround.

Comment: Perhaps you could get a reference to the Video object from the view parameter in WebChromeClient#onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) when newProgress == 100?I haven't tried this so I post it as a comment.

Comment: Have a look into MediaelementJS (http://mediaelementjs.com). I use this library in my quirli media player (http://quir.li) for various media formats, including Youtube videos. See the Youtube Example.

Answer (score 1):

### For future viewers

**YouTube now has a player API:**
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

**Where you can easily place a view in the xml and handle it in activity, here are the examples:**
https://github.com/youtube/yt-android-player

Answer (score 0):

Try This One:

```
    wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int w1 = (int) (metrics.widthPixels / metrics.density), h1 = w1 * 3 / 5;                
    String item="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3FFyT039tJ0";
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setWebChromeClient(chromeClient);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

    try {
        wv.loadData(
                "<html><body><iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html5\" width=\""
                        + (w1 - 20)
                        + "\" height=\""
                        + h1
                        + "\" src=\""
                        + item
                        + "\" frameborder=\"0\"\"allowfullscreen\"></iframe></body></html>",
                "text/html5", "utf-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And write a webchrome client like this:

```
private WebChromeClient chromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {

        super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
        if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {
            FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view;
            if (frame.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView) {
                VideoView video = (VideoView) frame.getFocusedChild();
                frame.removeView(video);
                video.start();
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody wants to use `WebView` yet to play youtube videos, two considerations:

1. Depending on Android version, it can't be possible. Android version 4.x through `WebView` can't do that (or i didn't find the way :) As I posted
   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31591010/youtube-iframe-player-wont-show-videos-in-android-4-x-webview/38410424#38410424)
2. If you are in Android 5 or upper, you have to set the `WebChromeClient` to the `WebView` component: `setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());`

Hope it helps!