# How to play inline html 5 video on WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

How I can play html5 video embedded in html page on web view.
Please provide descriptive example.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See documentation on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html in  HTML5 Video support section.

Comment: I already gone through this document but the implementation is not clear. I am looking for an example.

Comment: refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video