# How to get HTML5 video URI in HTML5VFullScreen$SurfaceVideoView in Android 4.0?

Tags: android, html, video, uri, surfaceview

I am trying to get a HTML5 video URI when the user clicks the fullscreen button in the video control bar. According to [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/webkit/HTML5VideoFullScreen.java), the HTML5 video view in Android 4.0 is a SurfaceView, not a VideoView.

Could someone tell me how to get the URI in SurfaceVideoView? This is my code. Thanks a lot.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
  @Override
  public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
    super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
    if (view instanceof FrameLayout){
      final FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view;
      if (frame.getFocusedChild() instanceof SurfaceView){
        SurfaceView video= (SurfaceView) frame.getFocusedChild();
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: exact same problem. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Easy, using **reflection**. Put this inside of the `onShowCustomView()` method:

```
android.net.Uri mUri = null;

try
{
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Class _VideoSurfaceView_Class_ = Class.forName("android.webkit.HTML5VideoFullScreen$VideoSurfaceView");

    java.lang.reflect.Field _HTML5VideoFullScreen_Field_ = _VideoSurfaceView_Class_.getDeclaredField("this$0");

    _HTML5VideoFullScreen_Field_.setAccessible(true);

    Object _HTML5VideoFullScreen_Instance_ = _HTML5VideoFullScreen_Field_.get(((FrameLayout) view).getFocusedChild());

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Class _HTML5VideoView_Class_ = _HTML5VideoFullScreen_Field_.getType().getSuperclass();

    java.lang.reflect.Field _mUri_Field_ = _HTML5VideoView_Class_.getDeclaredField("mUri");

    _mUri_Field_.setAccessible(true);

    mUri =  (Uri) _mUri_Field_.get(_HTML5VideoFullScreen_Instance_);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{   
}

if (mUri != null)
{
    // There you have, mUri is the URI of the video
}
```