# Android - Get Webview Media Player instance

Tags: android, webview, html5-video

I have a problem.  When I play HTML 5 video object in my webview (`<video>`), the LogCat returns several error messages like this one:

```
E/MediaPlayer(17981): mOnBufferingUpdateListener is null. 
Failed to send MEDIA_BUFFERING_UPDATE message.
```

I understand that several listeners are not implemented yet but I am not able to get the player instance.

**EDIT**

I am on ICS (4.0.3) and I have already tried this solution :

- [WebView and HTML5 <video>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video)

Comment: What device are you on? I see this only with a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.0.4.

Comment: It is a Galaxy Tab 10.1

Comment: same issue....i have that same tablet with android 3.2 i think it was, and no problems....now i update it to 4.0.4 and just using mediaplayer for streaming radio, play an audio whatever....starts the log to get full of that error every second.....and it doesnt matter stop it or whatever, until restart the app it continues :(