# webview crashing on vimeo videos

Tags: android, webkit, android-webview

I am triyng to play vimeo videos full screen in a WebView, but my application is crashing. I basically copied this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10912199/837746 and changed Test.java to load http://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/54596361

After opening the video full screen and starting playback, exiting the video full screen via the back button works fine during playback, but letting the video complete (you can manually skip ahead to almost the end of playback) and having the WebChromeClient.hideCustomView() hide the view automatically after playback causes my app to crash most of the time with a seg fault:

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x59335940 (code=2), thread 27554 (WebViewCoreThre)

Is there an additional workaround I need to do? I tried setting hardwareAccelerated=true in the manifest and plugin state to on in the webview, but it didn't help. I am on Jelly Bean 4.2.1.

Comment: did you get the solution. I am also getting the same error. Can you please help me on this?