# Play html5 video inside webview doesn't work

Tags: android, android-webview, html5-video

I have a web that supposed to play an embedded html5 video inside it.
the problem is that in samsung galaxy s4 the video does not play but in nexus 4 it does
(android version is 4.2.2 in both).

i added `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to the manifest in the activity.

the web view settings are:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);         
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);         
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(false); // zoom y/n
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false); // true = like desktop
webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);                              
webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

and the html5 code is:

```
mDataHtml = "<!DOCTYPE HTML> " +
                        "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" > " +
                            "<head>" +
                            "</head> " +
                            "<body style=\"margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0; background-color:#343434;\"> " +
                                "<iframe src=\"http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/" + mVid + "\" width=\"" + "100%25" + "\" height=\"" + "100%25" + "\" frameborder=\"0\"background-color:\"#343434\">" +
                                "</iframe> " +
                            "</body> " +
                        "</html> ";
```

I could not find any help to my issue when i searched for that.
your help is much needed.
thank's in advance.

Comment: Did you get it to work? I am facing the same problem

Comment: what we finally did is getting the mp4 video from the web and starting a video player to play it

Answer (score 0):

In the Android Manifest, try adding `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`.

If that doesn't work try looking at [WebView and HTML5 <video>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video).

Comment: added it programmtically:
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
and also in the manifest