# youtube video not working in android webview

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube

***i am trying to play a youtube video in android webview.. The following are the things that i have done***

**VideoWebview.java :**

```
String URL = "http://www.youtube.com/results";

WebSettings settings = volWebview.getSettings();

settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

volWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());   

volWebview.setInitialScale(1);

volWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

volWebview.loadUrl(URL);
```

**webview_file.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i have added `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to the manifest file

***The url is getting loaded.. but when tried to play a video, its not playing.
Any help regarding the same will be highly appreciated..
Thank you..***

Comment: you have to use youtubeAPI for playing youtube videos.

Comment: see this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663001/android-webview-not-playing-youtube-videos @Amith_Nagaraj

Comment: thanks a lot.. ya i will try to do that way :)

Comment: Hope this link helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708890/youtube-video-not-playing-in-webview-android/14743726#14743726

Comment: androiduser : thanks. but this worked for me : public static final int USER_DESKTOP = 1;
wv.getSettings().setUserAgent(USER_DESKTOP);

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set internet permission in your manifest file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: no its not solved.. is youtube api integration the only best way to implement it??

Comment: ya sure. i have updated the code above.. pls check it out.. Thanks a lot in avance

Answer (score 0):

In place of `webview` use `VideoView` this is working for me see this one

Activity.java

```
   private VideoView myVideoView;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.videoplay);

     videoplay();

 }
   private void videoplay() {   

    myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);    
    myVideoView.setVideoPath(DATA_PATH); // this is url path
    myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    myVideoView.requestFocus();      

}
```

videoplay.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for instant repy.. i have a situation where in i have to load a youtube link in my webview. when clicked on it, it has to start playing video on the same page.. how to achieve this??