# Android playing youtube video within webview

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, youtube, android-video-player

[WebView and HTML5 <video>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video) (using Surendra and Malenkiy's answer)

I followed whole above thread and many other articles/question online and got the youtube video to work eventually with webview however it opens in a new intent. I want it to play on the same page within specified web view.

Has someone dealt with something like this. I would appreciate your suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Hope someone here knows the answer for this.