# how to play youtube videos in webview in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, youtube

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Context context;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;

    Button btnload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadvideo);
    btnload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

            web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            web.zoomIn();

            web.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com");
        }

    });

}
```

};

am using my mobile as emulator and the youtube gets loaded but the video is not playing..

Answer (score 0):

see this url, It is useful for me

[WebView and HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video?answertab=votes#tab-top)

for more details you also see this android developer site link for [webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)