# Flash is not loading in Web view in Android

Tags: android, webview, flash

I am trying to Load a webview in Android. Where web page have a swf file but it is not loading. I know there are many question and answer on same topic but no one helped me.

I have already targeted it version 11. And I have put `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` too in manifest.xml file.

[image]

My code is here-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    String url="http://mypages.com/Ch_001/ScoPage.html";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
        settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.setInitialScale(100);
        // wbView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());


    }
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
                SslError error) {
            Log.e("Error VAGARO", error.toString());
            handler.proceed();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: flash is not supported on android anymore

Comment: @tyczj but when i use youtube video url its working fine why?

Comment: pretty sure android uses html5 for youtube videos

Comment: @tyczj so what should i do for my problem? I have to do it any how.

Comment: @tyczj Thanks Friend, finally I got solution. I got a flash apk which work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After one week struggle I got a Flash player from Macromedia, which works for me.

1. You can search in Google for-"Flash Player 11.1.for Android 4.0 - Macromedia - Adobe" or install APK from [this link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/installers/archive/android/11.1.115.17/install_flash_player_ics.apk&ei=cWHIUt7VJaen0AX114GoDg&usg=AFQjCNG7r1emPSGdLTvKGM2n_0xWU79xuQ&sig2=VyNfVCZzfqdhOf5GPAttwA&bvm=bv.58187178,d.d2k).
2. Install this apk in your Android device.
3. And when you will open it, it will ask for choose default browser.
4. Choose any browser which support Flash (UC-Browser, Chrome etc).
5. Now run your any application it will load your Flash video.

Comment: I have the Flash apk already installed and it works in Dolphin. How can I manage to work it within a custom webview as well? `setPluginState` is assigned to `ON`.

Answer (score 3):

Add this code:

```
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks Friend, finally I got solution.

Comment: try this webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

Answer (score -3):

add `mWebView.loadUrl(url);`in onCreate

Comment: I try in my phone is ok .Do you run in phone ? And  install flash ? If                you want to html5,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video can help you

Comment: Thanks Friend, finally I got solution.