# I can't load SWF into webView android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-assets

I read this 3 questions

[Problem loading swf file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532303/problem-loading-swf-file-in-android)

[Flash is not loading in Web view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802288/flash-is-not-loading-in-web-view-in-android)

[Load an SWF into a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994116/load-an-swf-into-a-webview)

But I could not to load my SWF into webView

My code is here

```
WebView webView = new WebView(context);
    webView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    addView(webView);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + dir +  File.separator + webapp.getFolder() + File.separator + webapp.getSource());
```

My assets

[image: My assets]

Log

[image: my log]

after to call, the screen stay just white

Answer (score 1):

i think you missing this call

```
webvIEW.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```