# as enable or include flash android in webview?

Tags: android, flash, webview

Community, I hope you can help me, I need to see my webview as http://www.templatemonster.com/es/demo/44836.html flash and related pages .

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nambudenki.android.fow&hl=es and try to install flash player 11 .

I tested also placing android: 
 `hardwareAccelerated = "true "`  on the manifest
`mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled (true);` 
this deprecated and 
 `mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);` It does not work either .

I conducted tests in a kit kat LG G2 with 4.4.2

I hope you can help

Answer (score 0):

Check following link it may help you for 4.1 and earlier. 
[Flash is not loading in Web view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802288/flash-is-not-loading-in-web-view-in-android) .

After 4.1 support of flash is deprecated.
But you can use Dolphin browser to run webpages. But can not do so in webview.